# android custom button

Tags: java, android, string, button

i would like to create a custom button like this:

http://i77.photobucket.com/albums/j74/bertyhell/button.png?t=1279626910

but that doesn't work
i need to show the text on the buttons with absolute positioning relative to the buttons origin
all strings need to be changeable at runtime

but the button below can be a regular button

how can i do this?

if i create a button by inheriting from android.widget.button i have to draw the whole button myself?

is there an easier way?

**EDIT**

ok i tried the inherit from relative layout

like this:

```
    package be.smarttelecom.datacheck.views;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class AlertButton extends RelativeLayout {

        private TextView roomNumber;

        public AlertButton(Context context, String roomNumber) {
            super(context);
            try{
            this.alertId = alertId;
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView room = new TextView(context);
            room.setFocusable(false);
            room.setText(R.string.room);
            room.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            this.roomNumber = new TextView(context);
            this.roomNumber.setFocusable(false);
            this.roomNumber.setId(R.id.roomNumber);
            this.roomNumber.setTextSize(26);
            this.roomNumber.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            this.roomNumber.setText(roomNumber);

            }catch(Exception ex){
                Log.i("test", "problem during construction of alert button: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public void setRoomNumber(String number){
            roomNumber.setText(number);
        }

        public void setDescription(String description){
            this.description.setText(description);
        }
    }
```

when i add it like this:

```
        TableRow row2 = new TableRow(this);
        AlertButton alert = new AlertButton(this, "1","14","wc","krist");
        row2.addView(alert);
        container.addView(row2, 0);
```

i get an empty page and no errors at all

any idea what i did wrong?

how do i put the textfields on certain positions?
put them inside an absolute layout and add x an y coordinates?
(absolute layout is depricated, alternative?)

Comment: Make sure you're setting your Activity's setContentView(container) or something similar in your onCreate method.  Also, take a look at defining layouts in XML.  It will make your relative layouts a lot easier to deal with

Comment: You also didn't add a button to the AlertButton view. Just calling it a button doesn't make it magically work unfortunately :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to create a custom view that extends `RelativeLayout`.  You can then add 4  `TextView`s in whatever arrangement you wish with whatever customization you need.  To make it look and act like a button, you can add a button to your layout with the width and height set to fill_parent.  Make sure that your `TextView`s are not focusable and that the button is sent to the back of the layout.

Alternatively you can set the `RelativeLayout`'s properties in your custom view to be clickable=true and focusable=true.  Then add a drawable as your view background that looks like a button.  Use a selector to handle all the focused/pressed states like a real button does.  Details on how to do that can be found here: [Standard Android Button with a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color)

Comment: i tried methode 1
i edited the first post with new problems

it doesn't display the custom controller

thx for the help so far :)

Comment: @Berty Did you remember to setContentView(container) in your activity's onCreate?

Comment: yes i added it

i also tried to add a textview before and after the custom button

i get something like this
http://i77.photobucket.com/albums/j74/bertyhell/errors/custom_button.png

so the button isn't displayed 

i did set the setContentView
setContentView(R.layout.alerts);

Comment: @Berty Try setting an absolute height and width for the custom button.  It might just be the way you're defining layout.