# Android button with different background colors

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

i want to change the background-color of a button using a selector-xml-file. My approach is basically the one from the example at the bottom this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

i have a res/color/button_text.xml which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

and my layout contains the following code:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    **android:background="@color/button_text"** />
```

(** is only there to show you that i use android:background instead of android:textcolor)

this code crashes. it says "Binary XML file line #4  tag requires 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining drawable. But if I try it with android:textColor as described in the above link it works fine. So it has to be the background issue. I don't want to create a 9patch-png if it's not necessary (basically i just need a "clickable" rectangle so i use a button with a colored background)

Comment: Konstantin's answer has a typo - the line `item android:color="@color/black"` .......... I propose it should read item android:drawable="@color/black" ...........

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15880688/1352919

Answer (score 84):

As your error states, you have to define *drawable* attibute for the items (for some reason it is required when it comes to background definitions), so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/red"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/blue"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/black"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Also note that *drawable* attribute doesn't accept raw color values, so you have to define the colors as resources. Create *colors.xml* file at *res/values* folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <color name="black">#000</color>
     <color name="blue">#00f</color>
     <color name="red">#f00</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: item android:color="@color/black" s/b item android:drawable="@color/black"

Comment: You can now use `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"` in your Button attributes! More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686250/material-effect-on-button-with-background-color

Answer (score 31):

In the URL you pointed to, the button_text.xml is being used to set the textColor attribute.That it is reason they had the button_text.xml in res/color folder and therefore they used @color/button_text.xml

But you are trying to use it for background attribute. The background attribute looks for something in res/drawable folder.

check this i got this selector custom button from the internet.I dont have the link.but i thank the poster for this.It helped me.have this in the drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/yellow1"
                android:endColor="@color/yellow2"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@color/grey05" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/orange4"
                android:startColor="@color/orange5"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@color/grey05" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>        
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/white1"
                android:startColor="@color/white2"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@color/grey05" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

And i used in my main.xml layout like this

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="45dip"
            android:textSize="7pt"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="230dip"
            android:text="@string/welcomebtntitle1"
            android:background="@drawable/custombutton"/>
```

Hope this helps. Vik is correct.

**EDIT :** Here is the `colors.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="yellow1">#F9E60E</color>
   <color name="yellow2">#F9F89D</color>
   <color name="orange4">#F7BE45</color>
   <color name="orange5">#F7D896</color>
   <color name="blue2">#19FCDA</color>
   <color name="blue25">#D9F7F2</color>
   <color name="grey05">#ACA899</color>
   <color name="white1">#FFFFFF</color>
   <color name="white2">#DDDDDD</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: do you have the color.xml file to go along with this?

Comment: @electrichead - Yes i have it.I am editing my answer. please see.

Comment: I first saw this answer when I started working with Android and was I fightened off by the amount of XML code, but two months later I've come across it again, and it is great answer to the general problem of creating custom button colours, without using an image.

Comment: This answer is much more complete than the other one, thanks! In my case I removed the <stroke>

Answer (score 4):

You have to put the selector.xml file in the drwable folder.
Then write:
`android:background="@drawable/selector"`. 
This takes care of the pressed and focussed states.

Answer (score 2):

in Mono Android you can use filter like this:

```
your_button.Background.SetColorFilter(new Android.Graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter(Android.Graphics.Color.Red, Android.Graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply));
```

Comment: Background should read getbackground(). Another option is using filter like that : myButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(multiplier, bckgrd_color));