# Use of attr reference in selector StateListDrawable

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable, android-selector, android-attributes

I'm trying to reference `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` within an *XML* definition of a `StateListDrawable` to change the behavior of some of the states defined within the original:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_pressed="false" />
    <item android:drawable="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" />
</selector>
```

But this results in a crash:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040298 a=-1}
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:946)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:930)
  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:177)
  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:122)
  at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1332)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1291)
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:833)
    ... 46 more
```

What I don't understand is, why it actually works with a `LayerDrawable` which seems to be doing just the same code-wise:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:drawable="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" />
</layer-list>
```

Is it possible to use a `?attr/` within a `<selector>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**LayerDrawable** flexibility on the use of either a ***?attr*** or a drawable can be misleading. If you use the ***?attr***, it will try to set a custom theme attribute, but if you use a regular resource it will try to load a drawable entirely. Quoting from the LayerDrawable docs :

> May be a reference to another resource, in the form "@[+][package:]type/name" or a theme attribute in the form "?[package:]type/name".

StateListDrawables **only** expect drawables to be references as such:

```
@[package:]drawable/filename
```

Notice how ***?attr*** or type is omitted.

Reference : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to resolve any references in selectors. That's why we ended having all the files duplicated (we had the same issue with colors and theming).

You might want to have a look at those closed questions:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30757188/4310905
2. [Use attributes in selector - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318712/use-attributes-in-selector-android/26625621)

Answer (score 0):

Just define two of your selectors: e.g. selector_1.xml and selector_2.xml
And use them in your styles.xml:

```
<style ...>
<item name="themeChannelBackground">@drawable/selector_1</item>
</style>

<style ...>
<item name="themeChannelBackground">@drawable/selector_2</item>
</style>
```