# How to Change color of Button in Android when Clicked?

Tags: android

I am working on Android Application. I want to have 4 buttons to be placed horizontally at the bottom of the screen. In these 4 buttons 2 buttons are having images on them. The border of the buttons should be black color and the border should be as thin as possible. When I click the button, I want the background of the button should be changed to blue color without the color of border to be changed and should be remained in that color for some time. How can I achieve this scenario in Android?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change color of vector drawable path on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35625099/how-to-change-color-of-vector-drawable-path-on-button-click)

I flagged it as duplicate, you can check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55205149/3763032

Comment: Add android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" . Vote my answer below thanks

Answer (score 136):

One approach is to create an XML file like this in `drawable`, called whatever.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/bgalt" />

    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/bgalt" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bgnorm" />
</selector>
```

`bgalt` and `bgnorm`are PNG images in drawable.

If you create the buttons programatically in your activity, you can set the background with:

```
final Button b = new Button (MyClass.this);
b.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.whatever));
```

If you set your buttons' style with an XML, you would do something like:

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/mybutton"
  android:background="@drawable/watever" />
```

And finally a [link to a tutorial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html).

Comment: You can also replace those drawables in the XML file with colors definitions if you want to avoid using images.

Comment: @jshin47 an empic amount of trial and error.  I've written two books on Android development now :-)

Comment: @haseman - Can you post the links of those 2 books or share to me at brk0018@gmail.com. Would be glad to go through those and learn better

Comment: What if just colors not images?

Comment: @KalaJ have you found a solution ?

Comment: this solution is deprecated

Comment: Carefull to fill with color do not change the android:drawable to android:color just use "@color/xxx" instead of "@drawable/xxx"

Comment: Add android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" . Vote my answer below thanks

Answer (score 79):

Save this code in drawable folder with "bg_button.xml" and call "@drawable/bg_button" as background of button in your xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#004F81" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#222222" />
            <corners
                android:radius="7dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#89cbee"
                android:endColor="#004F81"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#4aa5d4" />
            <corners
                android:radius="7dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks man, using style you can reduce application size. good idea to not use drawable

Comment: On the other hand, xml vector-based drawables are usually worse for performance than images, especially on older devices. Don't optimize prematurely, but keep that in mind as well.

Comment: Add android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" . Vote my answer below thanks

Answer (score 11):

Try This

```
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: It could not change back to its original color.

Answer (score 10):

Refer this,

```
boolean check = false;
Button backward_img;
Button backward_img1;
backward_img = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bars_footer_backward);
backward_img1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bars_footer_backward1);
backward_img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        check = true;
        backward_img.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
});

if (check == true) {
    backward_img1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    backward_img.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

Comment: This will set the BG permanently, that is, if the user clicks the back button, the background will be red.

Comment: @methode: ok refer the new answer i have corrected the oldanswer

Answer (score 8):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- default -->
    <item
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:state_focused="false">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="1"
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#00a3e2" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- button focused -->
    <item
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:state_focused="true">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="1"
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#5a97f5" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="5dp"
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="5dp" />
        </shape></item>

    <!-- button pressed -->
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_focused="false">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="1"
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#478df9"/>
            <padding
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp" />
        </shape></item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to change the backgorund image or color of the button when it is pressed, then just copy this code and paste in your project at exact location described below.

```
      <!-- Create new xml file like mybtn_layout.xml file in drawable -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" /> <!--pressed --> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/normal" /> <!-- Normal -->
</selector>
  <!-- Now this file should be in a drawable folder and use this 
  single line code in    button code to get all the properties of this xml file -->

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/street_btn"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/layout_a" > <!-- your required code -->
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 6):

1-make 1 shape for Button
  right click on  drawable  nd new drawable resource file .
   change Root element to shape and make your shape.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1eyH.jpg)

2-now make 1 copy from your shape and change name and change solid color.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNL1E.jpg)

3-right click on drawable and new drawable resource file 
 just set root element to selector.

go to file and set "state_pressed"

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"android:drawable="@drawable/YourShape1"/>
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/YourShape2"/>

</selector>
```

4-the end go to xml layout and set your Button background "your selector"

(sorry for my english weak)

Answer (score 4):

Try this......

First create an xml file named button_pressed.xml
These are it's contents.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="false" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/icon_1" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/icon_1_press" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/icon_1_press" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_1" />
</selector>
```

Noe try this on your button.

```
int imgID = getResources().getIdentifier("button_pressed", "drawable", getApplication().getPackageName());
button.setImageResource(imgID);
```

button_pressed.xml should be in the drawable folder.
icon_1_press and icon_1 are two images for button press and normal focus.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this code to solve your problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/login_selected" /> <!-- pressed -->
  <item android:state_focused="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/login_mouse_over" /> <!-- focused -->
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/login" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

write this code in your drawable make a new resource and name it what you want and then write the name of this drwable in the button same as we refer to image src in android

Comment: hi sir @lmo I have given some explanation with the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am use this code (with ripple effect):

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:color="@color/color_gray">
<item android:id="@android:id/mask">
    <color android:color="@color/color_gray" />
</item></ripple>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onPressed(Button button, int drawable) {
            if (!isPressed) {
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_circle);
                isPressed = true;
            } else {
                button.setBackgroundResource(drawable);
                isPressed = false;
            }
        }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.circle1:
                onPressed(circle1, R.drawable.bg_circle_gradient);
                break;
            case R.id.circle2:
                onPressed(circle2, R.drawable.bg_circle2_gradient);
                break;
            case R.id.circle3:
                onPressed(circle3, R.drawable.bg_circle_gradient3);
                break;
            case R.id.circle4:
                onPressed(circle4, R.drawable.bg_circle4_gradient);
                break;
            case R.id.circle5:
                onPressed(circle5, R.drawable.bg_circle5_gradient);
                break;
            case R.id.circle6:
                onPressed(circle6, R.drawable.bg_circle_gradient);
                break;
            case R.id.circle7:
                onPressed(circle7, R.drawable.bg_circle4_gradient);
                break;

        }
```

please try this, in this code i m trying to change the background of button on button click this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

To deal properly for how long you want to have your button stay in your other color I would advise this version:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.on_click_drawable));
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        new java.util.Timer().schedule(
                                new java.util.TimerTask() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        ((Activity) (getContext())).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.not_clicked_drawable));
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }, BUTTON_CLICK_TIME_AFTER_RELEASE_ANIMATION);
                        break;
                    default:
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

BUTTON_CLICK_TIME_AFTER_RELEASE_ANIMATION indicates after how much time [ms] the button will reset to the previous state (however you might want to use some boolean to check that the button hadn't been used in between, depending on what you want to achieve...).

Answer (score 0):

Even using some of the comments above this took way longer to work out that should be necessary. Hopefully this example helps someone else.

Create a radio_button.xml in the drawable directory.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- An element which allows two drawable items to be listed.-->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_checked" /> <!--pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_unchecked" /> <!-- Normal -->
</selector>
```

Then in the xml for the fragment should look something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<RadioGroup
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RadioButton

    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:button="@drawable/radio_button"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" />        
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:button="@drawable/radio_button" />

</RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add 1 line in XML for the click item

**android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"**

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Then

<item android:drawable="@drawable/bottom_line_green" 
android:state_focused="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@color/white"  
android:state_focused="false"></item>
```

Answer (score -1):

hai the most easiest way is this:

add this code to mainactivity.java

```
public void start(View view) {

  stop.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
 start.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellow);
}

public void stop(View view) {
stop.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellow);
start.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
}
```

and then in your activity main

```
    <button android:id="@+id/start" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:onclick="start" android:text="Click">

</button><button android:id="@+id/stop" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:onclick="stop" android:text="Click">
```

or follow along this [tutorial](http://programondaspot.blogspot.com/2015/06/change-color-of-button-in-android-when.html)