# Android selector - Text color

Tags: android

the background of a button is set based on selectors defined as:

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:dither="true">
      <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
      <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focused" />
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal"/>
   </selector>
```

How do I define the button's text color based on its state (pressed / focused)? This doesn't work:

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:dither="true">
      <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked" android:textColor="#CCCCCCCC"/>
   </selector>
```

Comment: i think this post explains your problem 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882064/how-to-change-color-of-button-in-android-when-clicked

Comment: @LostMohican: MMhh, not really. I could set the stuff programmatically, but I'd rather prefer the "xml-way"

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out how to define the button's text color based on state?