# How to change a color for standard button?

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Standard Android Button with a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color)

I have 1 problem - I need to change a color for standard button. I do it using "background" property of button. But when I do it button will change it's shape - rounded corners will disappear, button won't change a color by click (hightlight), color of button won't be gradient. How can I fix this problems? I want to change button's color it to look like a standard button.

Comment: Check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color

Comment: please go through it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882064/how-to-change-color-of-button-in-android-when-clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options - one is using [statelist drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) for background and setting drawables for normal, pressed and focused button, and other is using [color filter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setColorFilter%28int,%20android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode%29), which will change color without changing basic appearance:

```
Button button = ...;
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFff0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY); //red for example
```