# I want to change the color of button when it clicked?

Tags: android, button, widget

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Change color of Button in Android when Clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882064/how-to-change-color-of-button-in-android-when-clicked)

I want to change the color of button when it clicked...
How i can do it? I don't want to do it by using drawable folder...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a `selector` , create a file xml in your `drawable/` folder and name it `bg_button.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/back_button_clicked" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/back_button_clicked" android:state_focused="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/back_button_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

and then in your xml layout , define your button like this :

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_button" />
```

**NB** : `back_button_clicked` and `back_button_normal` are `drawables` for the background of your `button`.
the drawable `back_button_clicked` will be the background of your button when it will be **clicked** , and `back_button_normal` will be the background of your button in **normal case**.

**EDIT :** here is a [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/) for more explanation . and here is [another one](http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-selectors.html)

Comment: I want to do it in my OnClickListener function..
Don't want use drawable ...
:(

Comment: there is no need to do it with onClickListener  , that's why selectors are here :)

Comment: Okkkiieee ..
i will try this now ..:)

Comment: see my edits NB  for explanation :)

Comment: This Button in xml file which in layout folder...
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/on_basket_but"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="@string/on_basket"
        tools:context=".MainPage" 
        android:background="@drawable/changecolor"
       />

Comment: in my java file ...

final Button on_but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.on_basket_but);
   
 on_but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
 {
   public void onClick(View arg0) 
  {
         on_but.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.changecolor);
  }
  });

Comment: and I create drawable folder in res , in that changecolor.xml file

i am not gettibg that what i can write in 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/back_button_clicked" android:state_focused="true"></item>   
in this tag..??

please tell me... :(

Comment: you don't need to set the `onclickListener` and change the backgroundResource of your button programmatically , just add the selector ( `change_color.xml`) on your `drawable/` folder, and specify the `android:background="@drawable/change_color"`  on your `Button `tag

Comment: see the toturial in my edits for more explanation.

Comment: yeah i tried your answer. but m not getting  that what to write in drawable xml file ?

Comment: you have two images( png)  that you want them to be the background of your button , put them in your drawable folder . see the tutorial that i've added to my answer and you will understand :)

Comment: you're welcome :) , accept the answer so others can get informations and help from it ^-*