# how to change button selection or clicked colour in android?

Tags: android

i have a button , so i want to change style when button is clicked . i have used button

style "oval" and background image. so when in click it action performing perfectly but

not highlighted .

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#82B210"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SettingActivity" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@drawable/bg"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/confess_logout_btn"
            android:background="@drawable/confessfeeds" />   

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/confess_logout_btn"
            style="@drawable/bg"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/confess_settings_btn"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/confess_settings_btn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/confess_settings_btn"
            android:background="@drawable/logout" />    

      </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805926/button-highlight-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this file in your drawable folder,

**btn_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_clicked_image" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_clicked_image" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal_image"/>

</selector>
```

In your button add this

```
 android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
```

Comment: your code working perfectly , but not need no change image only shadow or hover colour should be changed .

Comment: @PratapManishBhadoria:  replace btn_clicked_image withyour hover/shadow color/image,now you replace the default button image with "@android:color/transparent" (instead of this "@drawable/btn_normal_image")

Answer (score 0):

To achieve different looks for various states of your button, you'll need to do more than just set the background image.  You're going to need to define the various states in a drawable-xml file.   Here's a tutorial on how to do this:

http://undertowsam.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/design-custom-background-and-button-for-android-using-xml/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue"/>

</selector>
```

You have to write a selector like this and place it into /res/drawable . Then set this as background of your button. Say, the name of above file is button_background.xml , then you have to do like this. Problem solved.

```
<Button
............
............
android:background="@drawable/button_background" />
```