# Change color on state change for custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-view, android-styles

I have a custom `View`, which overrides `onDraw` and basically draws a custom shape with canvas.
I would like to change the color, when the view is touched.

Looking around StackOverflow, it seems like the [preferred way for Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882064/how-to-change-color-of-button-in-android-when-clicked) is to set up a drawable selector list with various colors set on `android:state_pressed` and `android:state_focused`.
However, that approach does not seem to work for me, as I am drawing the shape myself, and the color is set on my own `Paint` object.

Here's what I have now:

I set up custom attributes as such with a simple color attribute:

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomView">

  <attr name="color" format="color"/>

</declare-styleable>
```

I retrieve the color in `CustomView`'s constructor, and setup a `Paint`:

```
private final Paint paint;

...

TypedArray conf = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
  attributes,
  R.styleable.CustomView
);
Resources resources = getResources();
int color = conf.getColor(
  R.styleable.CustomView_color,
  resources.getColor(R.color.blue)
);
paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(color);
```

Finally, I use it in `onDraw`:

```
canvas.drawPath(shapePath, paint);
```

I started looking into a [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html), but I am unclear on how I would integrate it into my code. Any suggestions on how to achieve the selector list functionality for my custom view would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the easiest way to do it would be to change `Paint` object's color in on touch method of your custom view.

You could do it more less like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            paint.setColor(mPressedColor);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            paint.setColor(mNormalColor);
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

(where `mPressedColor` and `mNormalColor` store int values for pressed and normal colors - respectively)

Comment: thanks! seems to work pretty well. but, why would I need to remove the `final` keyword? I'm not reassigning the `Paint` object anywhere (works fine with `final`).

Comment: true that. at first I was thinking of a bit different approach (in which doing so was necessary). Let me edit my answer a bit then

Comment: also, remember that you might need to call `invalidate` to force redrawing (if no other changes can force it)

Comment: yup, I had to add that in my code, after each of the `setColor` calls

Comment: exactly what I was thinking about:)

Comment: also, would it be correct to `return super.onTouchEvent(event);` here? or should it just always `return true;` if I am handling the event?

Comment: Remember that you return `true` in `onTouchEvent` when you want to receive further motion events in this, lets say "motion event sequence". And that might not be the case. I set it up to `super.onTouchEvent(event)` cause I wanted this decision to be handled by View's onTouchEvent handler itself or any other onTouchListener that you or some1 else using your custom view might use.