# ImageButton background color change onClick

Tags: java, android, xml

First-time Android dev, though have used C# and Java in the past.

Trying to make a simple, Windows 8-like GUI. At the moment I have one tile (ImageButton) with a background color set in activity_main.xml.

```
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:onClick="changeColor"/>
```

And I have a function to change the color in MainActivity.java.

```
public void changeColor(){
    ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

Compiles fine, but every time I click the red square, the app crashes.

I'm assuming there's something fundemental about how Android is developed that I'm missing which is leading to a very obvious mistake. Is there a better way to be doing this rather than ImageButtons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is there a better way to be doing this rather than ImageButtons?**
Yes, ImageButtons are mainly for creating a 'clickable' image. If you simply want a colored button, a regular Button will do fine.

You can do this by setting your Buttons background right from XML using a [selector with a Drawable state list.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

A good example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3882151/1683141 (a color will also qualify as a Drawable)

**Why isn't my current code working?**
You should add the view as parameter to your method like this:

```
public void changeColor(View view){
   view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'll be adding images to the buttons later on - with transparent backgrounds - I just wanted to get the color change working, more to make sure I had a handle on Android generally than anything.

Comment: Ok, anyways, drawable state list backgrounds will also work for ImageButtons, so in case you prefer a full XML solution this will work to.

Comment: I would actually. I'm implementing this as I type. :)

Answer (score 3):

> Compiles fine, but every time I click the red square, the app crashes.

Because  when adding `android:onClick` in xml then *method must be public and accept a View as its only parameter* which we want to call on View click:

```
public void changeColor(View view){
   ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
   btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! What view does this reference exactly? One hasn't been created anywhere, and it's not used anywhere else in this simple example that I can see.

Comment: @Serephucus: see here [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) for more information

Answer (score 2):

It's better to create a **selector** and set it as backgraund to the button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/button_pressed" />
    <item android:color="@color/button_normal" />
</selector>
```

Hope it'll help you. 
P.S. useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector)