# Toggle color of Button when pressed and released

Tags: android, button, colors

I've seen all the questions which have similar problems, but in all solutions Drawables are used. I don't want to use an Image or a Drawable.

I have a custom round `Button`. By default its color is set to `#00796B`.
Now when the Button is clicked it should change the color to `#00695C` for example and as soon as it gets released it should change back to the default color.

What do I have to do in `onClickListener` event of Button to achieve what I want?

Below is my code.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Vibrator mvibrate = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            mvibrate.vibrate(500);
        }

    });
```

I want to know that if there is any way we can use if condition to check the state of button and according to it do action?

EDIT :- I have successfully achieve what i wanted. Thanks guys for your answer and support.

Comment: Use selector as drawable to achieve that functionality

Comment: @Clairvoyant I refreshed it later didn't saw your comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Change color of Button in Android when Clicked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882064/how-to-change-color-of-button-in-android-when-clicked)

Comment: @Clairvoyant can you please help me with code how to achieve that functionality

Answer (score 0):

First make a xml in drawable folder save it with name button_selector.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#004F81" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#222222" />
            <corners
                android:radius="7dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#89cbee"
                android:endColor="#004F81"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#4aa5d4" />
            <corners
                android:radius="7dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Then in layout xml where you have defined your button set background of that button as :

```
<Button
.
.
android:Background="@drawable/button_selector"/>
```