# Android : Set a style on Button when it is clicked

Tags: android, styles

I have  an app with "menu" buttons. When I click on a button, a fragment is loaded. I want to assign a particular style on the button when it is clicked to indicate that it is active.

In js/html, it is so easy, I just add a class "active" but from I have read while searching online, it is not possible to change the style of a button in android once it has been set?? any alternative?

Comment: What do you intend with style? Are you trying to change the color or something when its clicked?

Comment: want to add a style "active" to indicate that the current button is "active". Yup ex. change the background.

Comment: By 'menu' do you mean the Toolbar buttons, or the Sidebar menu ?

Comment: Try changing the background color of the button in the onitemclicklistener of rhe button

Comment: I want to achieve it via style instead of setting the background

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to mark the button (option) as active while that fragment is loaded. You can try something like this :-

```
myActiveButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { 

        @Override 
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            myActiveButton.setPressed(true); 
            return true; 
        } 
    });
```

One thing you need to keep in mind, is while user selects the other button you will need to change the state of the active button. So, you can keep some sort of variable to know the selected button.

or you can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882064/how-to-change-color-of-button-in-android-when-clicked), consider the answer written by @methode.

Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: Or, you can just change the background color of the button `onClick`.

Comment: yup you can change the background color but it becomes tedious for maintenance... keeping track of the background color etc..

wanted something like jquery toggleClass