# How to change color of Button on button tap in android studio

Tags: android

I have created a `Button b` with its background colour as black. When i click on it I want its colour to change to green only for the time I have my finger on it, i.e. I keep focus on it.

Comment: Please provide the work you have done, and show us where you are having problems.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1726352/5250273

Comment: here's the same question answered clearly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882064/how-to-change-color-of-button-in-android-when-clicked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a selector in your button.

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" android:focusable="true"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background" />
```

here is code for list_selector_background XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/green"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/blue"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/black"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `onTouchListener` to listen when user presses the button (ACTION_DOWN) and when the user releases it (ACTION_UP)

```
b.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { 

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
       // reset the background color here
        b.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    }else{ 
       // Change the background color here 
        b.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    } 
    return false; 
   } 
});
```

Comment: Instead of registering touch event like this, we can make selector drawable using multiple colors/drawables for different states.

Answer (score 0):

> ACTION_UP --> A pressed gesture has finished, the motion contains the
>   final release location as well as any intermediate points since the
>   last down or move event.
>
> ACTION_DOWN --> A pressed gesture has started, the motion contains the
>   initial starting location.

You should set an **OnTouchListener** on your button.

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        }
    }
};
```

check [motion events](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)

Comment: as getColor() is deprecated you can use, btn.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorAccent));@Diptangsu Goswami

Answer (score 0):

make this xml drawable and use as background of button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/green"/> 
<item android:drawable="@color/black"/>
</selector>
```