# How to make clicked button highlighted with one color and set other all buttons with one color when button is cliked

Tags: android, android-button

Actually I have multiple rectangular buttons when i click on button i will get list view.now what the issue when i clicked on the button i need it highlighted with red color and other all buttons must be in green. Plzz help mee.

Activity:

```
if(name.isEmpty()||name==null){
    billnumber  +=name;
}
else{
    if(count==3){
        billnumber  +="  , "+name;
    }
    else if(count==2){
        billnumber  +="  , "+name;
    } 
    else if(count==1){
        billnumber  +=name;
    }
}


 if (count == 3) {
    id++;
    final Button dynamicTextView = new Button(this);
    dynamicTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(350,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    dynamicTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1c7900"));
    dynamicTextView.setText("Bill Numbers\n"+billnumber);
    dynamicTextView.setId(id);
    final Button dynamicinvnumber=new Button(this);


    if(id==(clickedid-1)){
        dynamicTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color
                        .parseColor("#cf0000"));
    }
    if(istouched){
    if (id == clickedid) {
        touchedlist=dynamicTextView.getText().toString();
        if(touchedlist.contains("Bill Numbers"))
        {
            touchedlist=touchedlist.replace("Bill Numbers","");
        }
        text=touchedlist;

        if(bumpedbillnumber!="0")
        {


            if(touchedlist.contains(bumpedbillnumber))
            {
                touchedlist=touchedlist.replace(bumpedbillnumber,"");
            }
            if(text.contains(bumpedbillnumber))
            {
                text=text.replace(bumpedbillnumber,"");
            }
        }
        dynamicTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color
                        .parseColor("#cf0000"));
    }
}
if(refreshlist!=1)
{
    if(id==1)
    {
        dynamicTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color
                        .parseColor("#cf0000"));
    }
}
if (invoice1 == null) {
    if (id ==1) {
        dynamicTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color
                .parseColor("#cf0000"));
    }

}
dynamicTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 30);
dynamicTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {           
        EnabledButton = dynamicTextView.getId();
        clickedid=dynamicTextView.getId();

        dynamicTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color
                            .parseColor("#cf0000"));
        dynamicTextView.setSelected(true);
        invoiceToDisplay = null;
        invoiceToDisplay = new ArrayList<String>();
        text = dynamicTextView.getText().toString();
        if(text.contains("Bill Numbers"))
        {
            text=text.replace("Bill Numbers","");
        }
        String s[] = text.split("  , ");

        invoice = text.split("  , ");
        System.out.println("s" + s[0]);
        istouched=true;
        refreshlist=1;
        if (s.length == 1) {

            if(s[0].contains("\n"))
            {
                s[0]=s[0].replace("\n","");
            }
            int invoice11=receiptlist.indexOf(s[0].trim());
            String invoiceselected=invoiceList.get(invoice11);

            tv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            footerText3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            footerText2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loadListViews(invoiceselected, listView1, headerButton
```

Drawable Xml:

```
<corners android:radius="3dp" />
  <solid android:color="#124a01" />

<stroke
    android:width="2px"
    android:color="#c8ea32" />
```

Comment: Check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882064/how-to-change-color-of-button-in-android-when-clicked] Button color changes when clicked

Comment: Just pass your clicked postionto adapter and set condilike below code   if (pos == position) {
                        mListview.setSelection(pos);
                        mCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        mCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_trans));
                    }

Comment: @sagar that ques is different i want clicked button being red and other to be green what ever button i clicked i want red color and remaining green

Comment: @vadivel I want to change color on cliked button not in list view buttons wont get position

Comment: Declare Array of button  then assign id to every button,then get clicked position id and use for loop to check conditio

Comment: yaa i did like this before

Comment: public void DeselectButtons() {

  for (int i = 1; i < id; i++) {

   if (EnabledButton != i) {
    if (this.findViewById(i) == null) {

    } else {

     this.findViewById(i).setBackgroundColor(
       Color.parseColor("#1c7900"));
    }
   } else {
    this.findViewById(i).setBackgroundColor(
      Color.parseColor("#1c7900"));
   }
  }

 }

Comment: and calle this method in code

Comment: suppose if i have 3 buttons and cliked frwd and if i come back to 1 or 2 then the 3 button remain in red after count id becomes 3 and it get struck at 3 button i meand 3 and other button showing red color

Answer (score 0):

> btn_selected.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:shape="rectangle">
     <solid android:color="red_color"/>
 </shape>
```

> btn_un_selected.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:shape="rectangle">
     <solid android:color="ordinary_color"/>
 </shape>
```

> btn_selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_selected"  android:state_selected="true"></item>

 <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_selected"  android:state_pressed="true"/>
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_un_selected"/>
</selector>
```

> In xml change button background of button

```
<Button 
........
android:background="@drawable/btn_selector/>
```

> in code change

```
btn.setSelected(!btn.isSelected);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating your buttons programatically, create them on xml, then retrieve their ids on your activity so you can access them; after setUp onTouchListener for them and inside those you should do this.

Define Rect rect and shouldPerformClick as global variables of your activity.

```
button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getActionMasked()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    changeButtonBackgrounds(v.getId());
                    shouldPerformClick = true;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    rect = new Rect();
                    v.getDrawingRect(rect);
                    if(!(rect.left < event.getX() && event.getX() < rect.right)){
                        shouldPerformClick = false;
                        resetButtonBackgrounds();
                    }
                    if(!(rect.bottom < event.getY() && event.getY() < rect.top)){
                        shouldPerformClick = false;
                        resetButtonBackgrounds();
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    resetButtonBackgrounds();
                    if(shouldPerformClick){
                        button1.performClick;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I would use a switch(viewID) on the changeButtonBackgrounds(), i think my whole approach requires a more boilerplate but its more optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Define button array `buttons` which are buttons from your XML file and a global variable `int selectedIndex=0`.

Make sure in your XML file that all buttons are green.

`selectedIndex` will be the index in the array of the last selected button.

Then, on every button in the array

```
    for (int i = 0 ; i < buttons.length ; i++)
        buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                buttons[selectedIndex]
                        .setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources()
                                .getColor(R.color.green, getTheme())));


                switch (view.getId()) {

                    case R.id.button1:
                        buttons[0].setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources()
                                .getColor(R.color.red)));
                        selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;

                    case R.id.button2:
                        buttons[1].setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources()
                                .getColor(R.color.red)));
                        selectedIndex = 1;
                        break;

                    .
                    .
                    .
                }

            }
        });
```