# How to change the color of a drawable on every click?

Tags: android-studio, button, drawable, porter-duff, colorfilter

I have a button with background set to a drawable to get rounded corners on it. I am trying to get the button to change color on every click without having to make a drawable of every color I want to use.

Currently I am trying to use PorterDuff to apply a color filter over the drawable's white background.

```
Drawable mDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),
    R.drawable.rounded_button, null);
mDrawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(0x800000ff,
    PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
```

When I load the app, the buttons remain white. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong or a better way to go about this?

Comment: Use `Random` method to generate RGB

Comment: @RajeshKushvaha The problem is not how I choose the colors, but how to make them appear on the buttons. Currently I can only get them to change color by editing the drawable xml file directly. The solution I am looking for is how to change the color of the drawable programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.button ); 
ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter( Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
myIcon.setColorFilter(filter);
```

Or

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
imageView.setColorFilter(getString(R.color.your_color));
```

Or

```
int iColor = Color.parseColor(color);

int red   = (iColor & 0xFF0000) / 0xFFFF;
int green = (iColor & 0xFF00) / 0xFF;
int blue  = iColor & 0xFF;

float[] matrix = { 0, 0, 0, 0, red,
                   0, 0, 0, 0, green,
                   0, 0, 0, 0, blue,
                   0, 0, 0, 1, 0 };

ColorFilter colorFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
drawable.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
```

Or

```
ImageView lineColorCode = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.line_color_code);
int color = Color.parseColor("#AE6118"); //The color u want             
lineColorCode.setColorFilter(color);
```

or Use This library
https://github.com/TakeoffAndroid/IconColorChanger/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/takeoffandroid/iconcolorchanger/IconChangerActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link.You can get some ideas.[How to Change color of Button in Android when Clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882064/how-to-change-color-of-button-in-android-when-clicked)