# I create a button in android studio, I want to change the background of button but it won't work

Tags: android, xml

[image]

It is a code that I wrote in my drawable folder, but it won't work either.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#EF9191" />
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ED3939" />
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear enough, please explain more, I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can either change the color programmatically or use a selector.
If you use a selector, make sure to use the correct state as described [here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable)

Also, see an example that might help [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3882151/19129727)

Answer (score 0):

Use this in XML of `Button` tag to change background instead of `android:background="#D33636"`

```
app:backgroundTint="#D33636"
```

Although, you need to define `app` in the parent layout as well:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```