# state_pressed remains true while onClick is running

Tags: java, android

I want to set a different background color for a button only while the button is being touched by the user.

But that color remains that way during the whole time onClick for that button is running even though I am no longer touching the button

Please help me find a solution to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#777777" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/black" />
</selector>
```

Comment: onClick execution should be quick. If it is a long-running operation it should be moved to a background thread.

Comment: Its a few seconds long. I'll try making the long part run outside of onClick

Comment: This will help you-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882064/how-to-change-color-of-button-in-android-when-clicked

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your on-click method takes a long time, You should add a second item for stating the case of the button not being pressed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#777777" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#000000"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/black" />
</selector>
```

Comment: thanks for sharing , but didn't work 