# selector for button not working

Tags: android

I want to change the background of the button when the button is unclickable.I have used selector for that but it is not working in the case when the button remains unclickable.

This is the selector file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false"  android:drawable="@drawable/button_lightgrey" />
    <item  android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_blue"/> 
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_darkgreen"  /> 
    <item  android:drawable="@drawable/button_lightgreen" /> 
</selector>
```

This is the button where i am using this selector file:

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/PrevButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="@drawable/ibtn"
                android:onClick="onPrevButtonClick"
                android:text="Prev" />
```

Please help me.All other functions are working in the selector file but only the unclickable button case is not working.Thanks

Comment: Hope, this will helps you: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738886/android-button-with-different-background-colors>

Comment: Sir,i want to make the selector working when the button is unclickable.Other states are working but only this one is not working.

Comment: Do you want a selector for disabled state? "unclickable" what you mean?

Comment: yes sir i need the selector for the disabled state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of button.setClickable(false) do button.setEnabled(false) and use the same selector xml.

Comment: Abhijit Chakra, whats your xml file?

Comment: I figure it out the problem is with xml file  <item android:state_enabled="false"  android:drawable="@drawable/button_lightgrey" /> if it is in first line only it works other wise it wont i dont know the reason.

Comment: the reason is, android takes the first state which is matched

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your selectors with below `selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/round_corner_button_sort" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/round_corner_button_sort" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/round_corner_button_sort" />

</selector>
```

Hope this helps you.

**Edit**

As per your comments you can't use selector for button which is the state as false(`button.setclickable(false);`) In this state you can't use your `selector`

Comment: Sir,i only want the selector state when the button is unclickable.

Comment: @user1662334 unclickable?? What do you mean by unclickable

Comment: means i have diasabled the button's state as nonclickable.  button.setclickable(false);

Comment: @user1662334 Do you think, when a button disabled when using `button.setclickable(false);` at that time, the selector will work?

Comment: Sorry sir ,but there might be some way to change the state of selector in this state also.

Answer (score 0):

this may helps you

i think in your selector file having issue try selector file like below

pls change images as you require

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_btn_repeat_pressed"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_btn_repeat_pressed"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_btn_repeat_pressed" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_btn_repeat"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

Comment: change true , false state as you require

Comment: sir what is the condition for the disabled state in the selector.