# Added background to android layout and buttons are hidden

Tags: android, android-layout

Added a background image to my layout and the buttons are hidden.  Is there a way to bring the buttons in front of the view?

http://oi45.tinypic.com/1180y0l.jpg

Heres my layout.xml

Layout:

```
android:id="@+id/newsletter_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/resort_background"
android:gravity="fill|top"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submitButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:onClick="submit"
    android:text="@string/submit" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/noThanksButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/submitButton"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/submitButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/submitButton"
    android:onClick="noThanks"
    android:text="@string/no_thanks" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/askLaterButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/noThanksButton"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/noThanksButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/noThanksButton"
    android:onClick="askLater"
    android:text="@string/ask_later" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean the buttons are hidden? I can see them very well.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed issue by adding color to the buttons.

Followed this post:   [Android button with different background colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738886/android-button-with-different-background-colors/3740351#3740351)

Thanks!