# Material effect on button with background color

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am using Android v21 support library.

I have created a button with custom background color. The Material design effects like ripple, reveal are gone (except the elevation on click) when I use the back ground color.

```
 <Button
 style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
 android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
 android:textColor="@color/white"
 android:textAllCaps="true"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Button1"
 />
```

[image: Background]
The following is a normal button  and the effects are working just fine.

```
<Button
 style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textAllCaps="true"
 android:text="Button1"
/>
```

[image: Default button]

Comment: This occurs because you replace the background with all the nice Material effects with a solid color. As to how you properly color a button while keeping the Material effects, no one on SO has been able to figure that out yet.

Comment: @SweetWisher The ripple and other effects are not applied in the button when I change the background color.

Comment: @NathanWalters But the default grey color is ugly. :-(

Comment: Believe me, I know... We'll be in great debt to whoever figures out how to do this properly.

Comment: The doc says : * Just add `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground` as the background.*

Comment: @Sathesh have you tried this code ?`<resources>
   
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
      <!-- Main theme colors -->
        <!--   your app's branding color (for the app bar) -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
 
        <!--   darker variant of colorPrimary (for status bar, contextual app bars) -->
 
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
 
        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>
</resources>`

Comment: @NathanWalters I don't know about Material effects but in previous styles, the `Button` press effect goes off when we put solid color on `Button`, but if we add alpha (little transparency) to that color, you can see the `Button` press effect. Have you tried this for Material effects?

Comment: Awesome answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32238489/1318946

Answer (score 437, accepted):

When  you use `android:background`, you are replacing much of the styling and look and feel of a button with a blank color.

**Update:** As of the [version 23.0.0 release](http://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/23/changes.html) of [AppCompat](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat), there is a new [`Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored`](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/JXHKyhsWHAH) style which uses your theme's `colorButtonNormal` for the disabled color and `colorAccent` for the enabled color.

This allows you apply it to your button directly via

```
<Button
  ...
  style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored" />
```

If you need a custom `colorButtonNormal` or `colorAccent`, you can use a `ThemeOverlay` as explained in [this pro-tip](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/JXHKyhsWHAH) and `android:theme` on the button.

**Previous Answer**

You can use a drawable in your v21 directory for your background such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:drawable="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
</ripple>
```

This will ensure your background color is `?attr/colorPrimary` and has the default ripple animation using the default `?attr/colorControlHighlight` (which you can also set in your theme if you'd like).

Note: you'll have to create a custom selector for less than v21:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/primaryPressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/primaryFocused" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/primary"/>
</selector>
```

Assuming you have some colors you'd like for the default, pressed, and focused state. Personally, I took a screenshot of a ripple midway through being selected and pulled the primary/focused state out of that.

Comment: Nice answer! Exactly what I was looking for, however needed to clean and rebuild before the project decided to identify the drawable in drawable-v21.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519979/coloring-buttons-in-android-with-material-design-and-appcompat

Comment: @ianhanniballake  i wonder on how to use material effect buttons with background on pre-lollipop version of android. please help and give me example and links.thanks

Comment: @ianhanniballake I wonder how to combine this working technique without losing rounded corners customization in those button

Comment: @ianhanniballake just a comment, drawable in ripple under <item android:drawable ... /> can't be a transparent color. In that case ripple won't be shown. It took me a while to realise that.

Comment: Dude a 100 thanks for that protip. Now I finally know ThemeOverlay was the answer. Been Solving this puzzle for the whole day. At last we devs a relatively simple and elegant solution for this mess.

Comment: This is working for me except that I can't get rid of the padding that is inherited by  Widget.Material.Button.Colored. Tried setting it to 0dp and -xdp to offset but I don't see any change. Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: With appcompat 23.1.1 and API 22, disabled and enabled state both take the theme's colorButtonNormal color.

Comment: @RémyDAVID - yes, `colorButtonNormal` is the disabled color, `colorAccent` is the enabled color as per [the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/res/drawable-v21/abc_btn_colored_material.xml) - if you're seeing differently, [file a bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Support%20Library%20bug)

Comment: Setting `android:theme` of the button didn't work for me to set the textColor. This answer helped me http://stackoverflow.com/a/32238489/3075340

Comment: @MicroR - correct. textColor is a style and should be used with `@style/`, it is not a theme attribute. You could use `textColorPrimary` as that is a theme attribute.

Comment: adding a theme to the button breaks onClick for some reason.

Comment: @PrashanthDebbadwar - that's not how themes work. Sounds like you should ask a new question with your code.

Comment: So does that mean there is no way to define custom button **shape** and keep all of the appcompat + material ripple w/out  rolling your own?

Comment: @tir38 - well, that wouldn't really be a [material button](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-raised-buttons) then would it? :-) You can adopt something similar to the 'Previous Answer' section and use a custom shape drawable instead of a color if you really want the ripple over a custom shape.

Comment: @ianhanniballake fair enough. I guess the specs do define a specific rectangular shape.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I guess i could just mimic how FAB works https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/lollipop/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButtonLollipop.java

Comment: @user1354603 Cleaning and rebuilding the project didn't work. I still don't see ripple effects.

Comment: I am getting ripple effect but it is very difficult to observe. is it because of color I am using?

Comment: What's if needed not only change color, but set drawable as background (needed keep material design effects)?

Comment: Now the `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored` style which uses your theme's `colorSecondary` for the enabled color instead of the `colorAccent`.

Answer (score 95):

There is another simple solution to provide custom background for "Flat" buttons while keeping their "Material" effects.

1. Place your button in ViewGroup with desired background set there
2. set [selectableItemBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#selectableItemBackground) from current theme as background for your button (API >=11)

i.e. :

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/blue">
    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Can be used for [Flat](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-flat-raised-buttons) buttons, it works on API >=11, and you will get ripple effect on >=21 devices, keeping regular buttons on pre-21 till AppCompat is updated to support ripple there as well.

You can also use [selectableItemBackgroundBorderless](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#selectableItemBackgroundBorderless) for >=21 buttons only.

Comment: You literally thought out of the box :-) Although this is one way of doing this, it might increase code coupling and using styles would be the recommended way.

Comment: This creates a flat button with color background, yes.
But the created button looks like a square, no rounded corners and shadow effects.

Comment: @SanketBerde Exactly. Cuz that's what "flat" button is.

Comment: The original question did not mention flat.
btw, if you have a <CardView> parent in your solution instead of <FrameLayout> , the resulting button will be raised and have shadows. This even works in pre-lollipop versions.

Comment: @SanketBerde great to know about `CardView` approach, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 90):

Here is a simple and backward compatible way to deliver ripple effect to raised buttons with the custom background.

Your layout should look like this

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/my_custom_background"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
```

Comment: @Galya make sure you are running on api 21+

Comment: api 21+ but not working. Applied on linear layout with clickable-true, background - different color, foreground- specified.

Comment: @Alex could you provide a snippet of code so I could understand your problem?

Comment: Since Button is a TextView and not a FrameLayout, `foreground` has no effect before 23. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7zID6xtLQAhVrlFQKHXLQDegQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F33379534%2Fcall-requires-api-level-23-getforeground-error-but-is-a-framelayout-method-s&usg=AFQjCNFPD5nnBfbJw4vvlAf5n9VAakv-pw&sig2=tXMNIibafvvsRgh6PLS3ng

Comment: If you are using it with TextView don't forget to set clickable property to true.

Comment: but the effect showing button's corner as rectangle but the button drawable was round shape.

Comment: Requires api level 23!

Answer (score 25):

I ran into this problem today actually playing with the v22 library.

Assuming that you're using styles you can set the `colorButtonNormal` property and the buttons will use that color by default.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primaryColor</item>
</style>
```

Outside of that you could still make a style for the button then use that per button if you needed an assortment of colors (haven't tested, just speculating).

Remember to add `android:` before the item names in your *v21 style*.

Comment: For an assortment of coloured buttons, see other Robert's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31825439/1617737

Comment: With the background colour now set, is there also a general attribute I can use in the above code block to specify the button text colour?

Answer (score 25):

The @ianhanniballake's answer is absolutely correct and simple. But it took me few days to understand. For someone who don't understand his answer, here is more detail implementation

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        style="@style/MaterialButton"
        ... />


<style name="MaterialButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/Theme.MaterialButton</item>
   ...
</style>


<style name="Theme.MaterialButton" parent="YourTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/yourAccentColor</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/yourButtonNormalColor</item>
</style>
```

===Or===

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialButton" />

<style name="Theme.MaterialButton" parent="YourTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/yourAccentColor</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/yourButtonNormalColor</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Your answer was the last piece of the puzzle for me. One can also write `colorButtonNormal` in the base theme `@style/AppTheme`. This gives a default color to AppCompat to colorize the buttons accordingly. And then can use your answer to theme a view individually.

Comment: Is it `android:theme="Theme.MaterialButton"` or `android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialButton"`

Comment: @osrl It's `android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialButton"`. Thank you for your correctness.

Answer (score 24):

With AppCompat (22.1.1+) you can add a style like this:

```
<style name="MyGreenButton">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#009900</item>
</style>
```

And use it by just applying the style:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    style="@style/MyGreenButton"
    android:layout_width="match_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="A Green Button"
    />
```

Programmatically changing the color, I found that the only way to update the color (on API 15 or 16) was to use the 'background tint list' instead.  And it doesn't remove the nice radial animation on API 21 devices:

```
ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(new int[][] {{0}}, new int[] {0xFF009900}); // 0xAARRGGBB
button.setSupportBackgroundTintList(colorStateList);
```

Because `button.setBackground(...)` and `button.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(...)` do not change the button color on API 15 and 16 like they do on API 21.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly for me (even if using Button in xml layouts as AppCompat inflater replaces it with AppCompatButton)

Comment: Use `ColorStateList.valueOf( ... )` to construct a simple `ColorStateList` of only one color.

Comment: colorAccent and rippleColor do not work in the style

Comment: Thank you for this post.
What worked for me: `ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(myButton, ColorStateList.valueOf(myColor);` 
Javadoc for `setSupportBackgroundTintList` says it should be called this way.

Answer (score 12):

I used the backgroundTint and foreground:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="10sp"/>
```

Comment: afaik there is no necessity for the foreground attribute as backgroundTint doesn't override the standard ripple

Answer (score 7):

I came to this post looking for a way to have a background color of my `ListView` Item, yet keep the ripple.

I simply added my color as a background and the selectableItemBackground as a foreground:

```
<style name="my_list_item">
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:foreground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/my_list_item_height</item>
</style>
```

and it works like a charm. I guess the same technique could be used for buttons as well. Good luck :)

Answer (score 6):

Use `backgroundTint` instead of `background`

Comment: for pre-lolipop you should set the tint in code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735890/lollipops-backgroundtint-has-no-effect-on-a-button

Answer (score 6):

If you are interested in ImageButton you can try this simple thing :

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_button"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
/>
```

Answer (score 5):

`v22.1` of `appcompat-v7` introduced some new possibilities. Now it's possible to assign a specific theme only to one view.

> Deprecated use of app:theme for styling Toolbar. You can now use
>   android:theme for toolbars on all API level 7 and higher devices and
>   android:theme support for all widgets on API level 11 and higher
>   devices.

So instead of setting the desired color in a global theme, we create a new one and assign it only to the `Button`

**Example:**

```
<style name="MyColorButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/myColor</item>
</style>
```

And use this style as theme of your `Button`

```
<Button
 style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Button1"
 android:theme="@style/MyColorButton"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're ok with using a third party library, check out [traex/RippleEffect](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect). It allows you to add a Ripple effect to **ANY** view with just a few lines of code. You just need to wrap, in your xml layout file, the element you want to have a ripple effect with a `com.andexert.library.RippleView` container.

As an added bonus it requires Min SDK 9 so you can have design consistency across OS versions.

Here's an example taken from the libraries' GitHub repo:

```
<com.andexert.library.RippleView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:rv_centered="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/> 

</com.andexert.library.RippleView>
```

You can change the ripple colour by adding this attribute the the RippleView element: `app:rv_color="@color/my_fancy_ripple_color`

Answer (score 3):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="#fff"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:text="test"/>
```

Use

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and the color will acept on pre-lolipop

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches explained in the great tutorial be Alex Lockwood: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/08/coloring-buttons-with-themeoverlays-background-tints.html:

**Approach #1: Modifying the button’s background color w/ a ThemeOverlay**

```
<!-- res/values/themes.xml -->
<style name="RedButtonLightTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/googred500</item>
</style>
```

```
<Button
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/RedButtonLightTheme"/>
```

**Approach #2: Setting the AppCompatButton’s background tint**

```
<!-- res/color/btn_colored_background_tint.xml -->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Disabled state. -->
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
          android:color="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
          android:alpha="?android:attr/disabledAlpha"/>

    <!-- Enabled state. -->
    <item android:color="?attr/colorAccent"/>

</selector>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/btn_colored_background_tint"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically applying the colors:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

    ColorStateList colorStateListRipple = new ColorStateList(
            new int[][] {{0}},
            new int[] {Color.WHITE} // ripple color
            );

    RippleDrawable rippleDrawable = (RippleDrawable) myButton.getBackground();
    rippleDrawable.setColor(colorStateListRipple);
    myButton.setBackground(rippleDrawable); // applying the ripple color
}

ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
        new int[][]{
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, // when pressed
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // normal state color
                new int[]{} // normal state color
        },
        new int[]{
                Color.CYAN, // when pressed
                Color.RED, // normal state color
                Color.RED // normal state color
        }
);

ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(myButton, colorStateList); // applying the state colors
```

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically:

```
 myMaterialButton.setRippleColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
```

For example:

```
 MaterialButton myMaterialButton = new MaterialButton(this);
 myMaterialButton.setLayoutParams(myButtonParams);
 myMaterialButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
 myMaterialButton.setRippleColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried this:

```
android:backgroundTint:"@color/mycolor"
```

instead of changing background property.
This does not remove the material effect.

Comment: This will not work for pre-Lollipop devices (70% market share). Actually it has been backported but Android Studio as of now still shows errors when using it without the android prefix.