# selectableItemBackground as item in layer-list

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable

I've copied a file from the Google IO Schedule app source (https://github.com/google/iosched) namely

**selected_navdrawer_item_background.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/backgroundColor">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#12000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="?android:selectableItemBackground"/>
</layer-list>
```

I want to use this to highlight the currently selected item in a NavigationDrawer. My problem is, when I launch my app, it throws an exception.

This is the important line I think.

```
caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #22:
<item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
```

Line # 22 is this one

```
<item android:drawable="?android:selectableItemBackground"/>
```

I don't know what the problem is, I copied this over from source without adjusting it. It's working fine in their app.

I tried to change `?android:selectableItemBackground` to `?attr/selectableItemBackground`, but it gives me the same exception.
I can't seem to find any other suggested solutions.

If anyone knows what's causing this, please help me.

Comment: Do you use Appcompat library?

Comment: I haven't tested this anymore, but I suppose this can be used as a workaround. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686250/material-effect-on-button-with-background-color

Comment: I tested it and it works like a charm in my project.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It works but from api **v21**. So, you can go ahead and use it on devices with **Android Lollipop** and newer. If you want support older system versions you can put this xml into **drawable-v21** folder and prepare new xml in drawable folder with the same name.
For example:

**drawable/selected_navdrawer_item_background.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <solid android:color="#12000000" />
</shape>
```

Google IO app does the same thing: 
[here is file from drawable folder](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/d7bab489f24cae9d33f84295e0820ebbb3f3ad4c/android/src/main/res/drawable/selected_navdrawer_item_background.xml) and 
[here is file from drawable-v21 folder](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/d7bab489f24cae9d33f84295e0820ebbb3f3ad4c/android/src/main/res/drawable-v21/selected_navdrawer_item_background.xml/)

Comment: No idea why this answer was negative (I upped it), as it's perfectly valid. Thank you!