# appcompat-v7:22.0.0 theme issue when creating UI programmatically

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I've run into serious problem with theme after updating to appcompat-v7:22. Issue described below does not occur with appcompat-v7:21

I have activity with one statically added fragment. Fragment view is created programmatically only (no layout is inflated). Final activity view contains 2 buttons: one created directly in Activity layout, second added programmatically via Fragment. **Second button should look similar to the first one as no custom styles or attribute values are assigned:**

[image]

App theme extends `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`

**Activity layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="Super Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/myfragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.jskierbi.appcompat22test.MainFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Fragment class:**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        Button btn = new Button(getActivity());
        btn.setText("Click me!");
        layout.addView(btn);
        return layout;
    }
}
```

I've separated this issue to new project here: https://github.com/jskierbi/appcompat-v7-22-bug

Is this a bug or am I missing something?
Is it possible to make a workaround for this?

**Edit**

This is not a bug. `<Button>` widget defined in layout inflates to TintButton object in view hierarchy. Possible fix is to create TintButton instead of Button in code. **Warning** TintButton is inside internal package so it is not supposed to be used in production code.

Comment: is it working in production code?

Comment: No we have not this into production. It is working as long as TintButton is exposed, but this is not guaranteed to stick around with new SDK version.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand your solution: i have the same problem, what i must do if i want to change the button color (for Android KitKat and Lollipop), maintaining ripple effect?

Comment: This is not in scope of this question. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686250/material-effect-on-button-with-background-color

Comment: @jskierbi ty, the link is helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know v21 had no support for automatically styling buttons with material guidelines. I assume now the button created at runtime is not styled, which yes, might be considered a bug.

Possible workaround that comes to mind (can't test it right now) is calling, rather than `new Button()`, `new TintButton()`, where TintButton is the class defined in the support library, assumed to be a material styled version of `Button`.

I think it should be `android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintButton`.

Comment: What is interesting, widget <Button> in layout is inflated to TintButton in view hierarchy. Changing Button in code to TintButton fixes the issue. Thanks,

Comment: So, this is not a bug, its a feature :)

Comment: I don't know if `internal` stuff is really supposed to be used. You could try adding at runtime, rather than `Button`, an `EditText` or `CheckBox` or some other widget that was already tinted in v21. They also have proper tinted classes.

Comment: More than using this in production code I've been into investigating this feature. Now I understand more, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Problem was fixed with appcompat rev 22.1 on April 22. Now you can use the normal Button or the new AppCompatButton [See here](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html)