# ImageButton image scales when adding background attribute, while using scaletype to position image

Tags: android, xml, drawable, imagebutton, scaletype

I am having an issue with a drawable in an ImageButton.

I am trying to align the white arrow (seen in the picture below) in the right side of the imagebutton. I succeed to do so while not using a background color, by using scaleType="fitEnd".

[image: Button - correct arrow, wrong background color]

```
            <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/arrowUp"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd" />
```

However, when trying to add a background color, the arrow image scales up in size, so it doesn't look like intended (seen in picture below).

[image: Button - wrong arrow size, correct background color]

```
            <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/arrowUp"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:background="#054365" />
```

Is there a way to get the proper arrow size & positioning while still changing the background color of the ImageButton while using scaleType="fitEnd", or do i have to use another approach?

Comment: Have you tried to create a `xml` drawable resource to use ad the background of the button instead of use directly the color?

Comment: I have considered it. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a way to do this programmatically first.

Comment: try android:backgroundTint="#054365" instead of  android:background="#054365"

Comment: @bhargav you're the man. That fixed it instantly, should probably have tried out that one before asking this question.

If you can post it as an answer, i will accept it.

Comment: set `adjustViewBounds` attribute true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
android:backgroundTint="#054365"
```

instead of

```
android:background="#054365"
```

To change the button color. This is a simple hack.

For more info refer [Material effect on button with background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686250/material-effect-on-button-with-background-color)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="Your image path"
    android:scaleType="fitEnd"
    android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"/>
```

The "backgroundTint" attribute will work API level 21 and higher. If below API level 21 the application simply ignore the attribute and it is not an error.