# Colored Buttons in Android Studio look bigger than original

Tags: android

When you set `android:background` to another color, the `Button` appears more bigger. Also, the lines surrounding the `Button` is gone. Why is this?

Comment: When you set color it draws rectangle area by this color but default it can use some drawable or nine patch picture

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'm using Marshmallow target, must be the Appcompat.

Comment: You should add that as an answer so I could nominate it.

Comment: Use [shape](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) to customize background

Comment: You should be using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26686433/1676363) if you want to colorize a button but keep all the standard styling/look and feel

Comment: Thanks, all. It's a duplicate, seems so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set color it draws rectangle area by this color but default it can use some drawable or nine patch picture. Use [shape](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) to customize background or override styles. If you need to apply style only for some view you can use xml attribute `style`.

```
<style name="MyCoolStyle" parent="base style of view" >
</style>
```

In layout xml:

```
<YourView
   style="@style/MyCoolStyle"/>
```