# Android - Display file path in Toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, horizontalscrollview

I am searching for a way to display a file path in the toolbar like this:
[image]

It needs to be clickable and should be swipeable if it's a long path. (Or small device).

I thought about using a `HorizontalScrollView` with a `TextView` and `ImageView`, but don't know if that is the best way to accomplish this. Is there a better (simpler) way to do this? Thanks!

**Edit:**

With thanks to @aelimill I found out that a `RecyclerView` can go horizontally, but I'm still having some issues. If you click on the text in the previous screenshot it shows this:

[image]

But for me (after I set the custom list item to clickable) it is like this:

[image]

(Look at the click animation)

How can I display the circle animation just like other `ActionBar` items?

Comment: RecyclerView should be optimal for this.

Comment: @aelimill Didn't knew the RecyclerView could go horizontal. This will be the perfect solution.

Comment: LinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) - you can choose orientation :)

Comment: @aelimill Thanks for your suggestion, please look at my edit.

Comment: Do you want ripple effect? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686250/material-effect-on-button-with-background-color

Comment: @aelimill Yes. I did what was in the answer to get a ripple effect, but it does not display "outside" the `TextView`. It displays the ripple effect in a rectangle.

Comment: @ThomasVos:
have u got the solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using a `RecyclerView` as @aelimill suggested. This is the custom list item I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_white_24dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:minWidth="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> Use `selectableItemBackground` instead of `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` to support pre lollipop devices. (It wont be a circle animation, but a rectangle animation).

[image]