# Add ?attr/selectableItemBackground to View and set Background Color

Tags: android, android-view, android-drawable, android-attributes

I have a `View` that I created programmatically, and I want to have a ripple effect when I select it.  I was able to get that working using `?attr/selectableItemBackground`.  However, I also want to set the background color of the `View` when I select it.  I've tried `setBackgroundResource(selectableAttr)` and then `setBackgroundColor(colorSelectBackground)`, but the color seems to overwrite the resource, so I only have one or the other.  Here's my code:

```
int[] attrs = new int[]{R.attr.selectableItemBackground};
TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
int backRes = typedArray.getResourceId(0, 0);

public void select() {
    view.setSelected(true);
    view.setBackgroundResource(backRes);
    view.setBackground(colorSelectBackground);
}

public void deselect() {
    view.setSelected(false);
    view.setBackground(colorSelectBackground);
}
```

Anyone know how I can use both `?attr/selectableItemBackground` and also set a background color?  Thanks!

**EDIT:**  To clarify, the view in question isn't a button, it's a `RelativeLayout`.

**UPDATE:**  I never really found a good solution for this.  The closest I got was using `View.setForeground()` to a `Drawable` from the `TypedArray`, i.e.

```
view.setForeground(typedArray.getDrawable(0));
```

The main drawback to this is that it's only available on API 23+.  Let me know if you come up with a better solution.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686250/material-effect-on-button-with-background-color

Comment: Thanks @ChantellOsejo, but I didn't have any luck with that answer, and I'm not using a `Button` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend creating a custom `View`, where you can get the `pressedColor`, `defaultColor` and `disabledColor` from the xml.

The following code would work for a Material styled button:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
{
    ColorStateList colorStates = new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed},
                    new int[]{}
            },
            new int[]{
                    pressedColor,
                    defaultColor});

    view.setBackgroundDrawable(isEnabled ? new RippleDrawable(colorStates, getBackground(), getBackground())
            : new ColorDrawable(disabledColor);
}
else
{
    StateListDrawable backgroundDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
    backgroundDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, new ColorDrawable(isEnabled ?
            pressedColor : disbledColor));
    backgroundDrawable.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, new ColorDrawable(isEnabled ? defaultColor :
            disabledColor));
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(backgroundDrawable);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ognian, both the `RippleDrawable` and `StateListDrawable` show the ripple effect, but the background color doesn't change.