# Changing color of rounded button with transparent background

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android, android-chips

How can I change color of rounded corners textView or button with transparent background like this [image]

I want when clicked again the button unselect , not only select

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android button with different background colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738886/android-button-with-different-background-colors)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the corners of a button round?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054562/how-to-make-the-corners-of-a-button-round)

Answer (score 3):

Add xml file in drawable folder bg.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <!-- you can use any color you want I used here gray color-->
    <stroke
        android:height="1.0dip"
        android:width="1.0dip"
        android:color="#ffee82ee" />

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <corners android:radius="7dp"/>
</shape>
```

and in layout

```
   <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:textColor="#ffee82ee"/>
```

It will work..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a selector with multiple state as drawable for background and text color.

```
  <Button
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:background="@drawable/selector_xml_name"
         android:layout_width="200dp"
         android:layout_height="126dp"
         android:text="Hello" />
```

drawable xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have different options:

- Just use the [**`MaterialButton`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) in the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) with the [`Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md#outlined-button) style and the **`app:cornerRadius`**, **`app:strokeColor`** attributes.

Something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:text="BUTTON"
        app:strokeColor="@color/myColor"
        app:cornerRadius="16dp"
        ../>
```

[image]

To achieve the selection of the buttons you can use a [`MaterialButtonToggleGroup`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButtonToggleGroup.md).

Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    app:singleSelection="true"
    ...>

   <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
      .../>

</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

- Use a [**`Chip`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Chip.md)

Something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry"
        app:chipCornerRadius="16dp"
        android:text="Chip"
        .../>
```

[image]