# Android - My own tab control

Tags: android, custom-controls

I don't like the way the tabs look with the native tab control in Android so I'd like to create my own control.  I can create and draw my own tabs in a horizontal LinearLayout at the top of the screen using a vertical LL, but how do I setup the various hidden tab contents in the XML and how do I show/hide them?

Any potential issues?

Comment: FYI, you can set a custom View for the contents of a Tab on Android 1.6+ (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setIndicator(android.view.View))

Comment: I want to change the way the tab itself looks, not the contents of the tab. I simply created three custom views and implemented onDraw and onTouch. I just don't know how to setup and switch between the various 'tab' pages.

Comment: I found a way to draw my tabs in XML. Based on the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used FrameLayout and its just a matter of setting the visibility. I'm not sure why this took so long to figure out, I must have been searching wrong online.

```
        tab1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tab2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [source code](http://source.android.com/source/index.html) for the existing tab control as a starting place to build your new widget. If you're truly just changing the look and feel, this is a much less error-prone option.

Comment: I'm hoping a button click to switch a view isn't too complicated. I just need to know how to create them and change them in the onClick handler. I already have the tabs working fine.