# How can I reproduce these buttons found in the official Twitter app?

Tags: android, image, button

[image]

How do I reproduce the two buttons at the bottom of the Twitter app in this screenshot (Update and Cancel)?  You can see a similar design pattern in the official Facebook app too when creating a Facebook message.  Are they created with 9 patch images or is it something easier than that (setting a background color and somehow keeping border/state press color changes to orange).

This would be really simple if Twitter had open sourced their official Android app like they said they would (but never did).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found out a way to do something very similar without using 9 patches [thanks to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color/1726352#1726352).

Screenshot:

[image]

Activity layout (just the bottom part):

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.75dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"   
        >
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/NavyBlue"
        >
            <!-- Buttons -->
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn_UpdateAlert" 
                android:text="Update Alert"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:textColor="@color/CarolinaBlue"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Cancel"
                android:text="Cancel"   
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:textColor="@color/CarolinaBlue"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Drawable button: res/drawable/button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/yellow1"
                android:endColor="@color/yellow2"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0.75dp"
                android:color="@color/grey" />
            <corners
                android:radius="10dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/orange1"
                android:startColor="@color/orange2"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0.75dp"
                android:color="@color/grey" />
            <corners
                android:radius="10dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>        
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/NavyBlue"
                android:startColor="@color/NavyBlue"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0.75dp"
                android:color="@color/grey" />
            <corners
                android:radius="10dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a 9-patch or you could look into creating your own custom components using the guidelines Google has in the SDK: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html.

It's basically just specifying XML tags to describe how you want your custom View to look like.