# how do I change the style of a button in android?

Tags: android, button, coding-style

I want to change the style of a button in an android app. here is a picture that has both kinds of buttons, the one that I have now, and the one that I want to switch to:

[image]

the kinds of buttons that I am using now, look like any of the letters on that keyboard. the ones that I want to use like like the arrows. I would I go about changing this. I prefer to do it in xml but I can do it in java if that is the only way. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the background of the Button to a png image with arrows! 
in XML use android:background="@drawable/yourimage"

To get more sophisticated control check here,

[Standard Android Button with a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color)