# Setting button color in Android

Tags: java, android, button, colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Standard Android Button with a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color)

i would like to make a red button in my android application.

i need it to be red from the start and i also need it to stay red after events.

is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 11):

Did you try at all to get some info about this? ;)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html Read that to know how to declare buttons

I use this personally (implying a Button has already been declared as button, as above):

```
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

This ensures that it looks like a Button after you apply the new color too. I had issues with `setBackgroundColor(int color)` on that note.

You can also use `Color.RED` instead of the Hex value that I put.