# how to change button color when it is clicked in android

Tags: android, button, widget

By default when button is clicked something like **orange color** will surround the button for short time, that indicates buttons is clicked. But this feature is not working when button contains background image. This is happening in list view too.why ? Any Ideas? TIA
I used **setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);** But here the color is applied and not gone...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a selector as your background resource :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_focus" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />
</selector>
```

This selector makes use of 3 separate drawables to change the image of the button , you may use the same image for pressed and focuses.

You need to put this XML into your drawables directory and use it as a background for your button.

For another solution refer : [Standard Android Button with a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color)

Answer (score 1):

i too had the same problem. so instead of setting the background color,i included three images of button in three different colors , so based on state focused,pressed,default the respective image will replace the other. and it looks like change in the color of the button.

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/c2"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/c1"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/c1" />
</selector>**
```

above is the content of the xml file,which must be assigned to the background of the respective button 
**android:background="@drawable/drawable_button**

hope this might be helpful for you