# Android Widgets with Custom backgrounds not getting Focus

Tags: android

I am using a button with my own back ground color in android and that button is not getting focus what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buttons normally will not have focus by touch. Also focus depends on the background.

So, check the background - it needs to be of type drawable with multiple states or you need to make a gradient. Check [Standard Android Button with a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color)