# android:background="@drawable/XXXX is ignored for a button in main.xml

Tags: android, xml, layout, drawable

I have tried copying several different examples, used shape layouts, tried images, etc. No matter what I do, it is a though the the background drawable is simply ignored. I intentionally put an error into the drawable xml to be sure it was being seen, that triggered an error. I have my drawable stuff in res/drawable.

Any ideas?

```
<Button android:id="@+id/buttonClose"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test"`enter code here`
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:onClick="closeScoreBoard"
    android:background="@drawable/button_close"
    />


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid   android:color="#FF0000"/>

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="8dip"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dip"
        android:topRightRadius="8dip"
/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Can you post your XML for the button?

Comment: Please add them in your the question and format them for easier reading.

Comment: done, slightly before your request ...

Comment: What is your background drawable? Is it an image? If so, what type? Are you seeing any errors in LogCat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing background is not ignored. Simply background is not visible because of the foreground drawable. You may find more info here: [Standard Android Button with a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color)

or ready to use sample here: http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/custom-color-buttons-for-android/

Comment: So what can I change to make it visible?

Answer (score 3):

Just use

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
```

It helped me.

Answer (score 1):

After searched everywhere, I got this solution and it's working fine.
**Go to values > theme**

1. Change the parent theme from Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar to "Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"
2. Paste this before ""

<stylename="Material.Theme"parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">