# Background for a button in android?

Tags: android, button, background

In my app I have set for a button the background to a certain color. I don't like how it looks like.The button is like a rectangle, with straight edges. I want that the button to have rounded corners. How is it possible?

Here is my button in xml :

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button" android:text="Participer au concours de photos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="410dip" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:background="@drawable/orange1"/>
```

Thanks...

Comment: Just try to give Round-corner image to its background.

Comment: This article can be helpful to you: http://appfulcrum.com/?p=105

Comment: hi , a simple search in stackoverflow can be very helpful : refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=button+with+rounded+corners+in+android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `selector`

```
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#24a1dd"
            android:centerColor="#158ee4"
            android:endColor="#37b8ee"
            android:angle="270"
            android:centerY="0.88" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#00ffffff"
            />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_focused="true" >
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#59bfe6"
            android:centerColor="#36aced"
            android:startColor="#91def7"
            android:angle="270"
            android:centerY="0.88" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#00ffffff"
             />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>        
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#e1e1e1"
            android:centerColor="#bdbebd"
            android:startColor="#f6f2f6"
            android:angle="270"
            android:centerY="0.88" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#00ffffff"
            />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Something like this should do the work. Just fix the color values. Which is the same as the the answer of this question [Standard Android Button with a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways :

1. Use 9 patch drawables (png image)
      here is complete tutorial [9 patch drawables: background of a customized Button](http://enadroid.blogspot.com/2011/04/9-patch-drawables-background-of.html)
2. Set xml drawable as background of your buttons.

Take a look here [Gradient buttons for android](http://www.dibbus.com/2011/02/gradient-buttons-for-android/).

And to know more about xml drawables :- 
[ANDROID XML DRAWABLES](http://androidtut.blog.com/android-xml-drawables/)