# Button Background Selector

Tags: android, button, background, css-selectors, drawable

I try to switch the background of Buttons if they are pressed. I build a Selector like the answer suggested here: [Standard Android Button with a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color)

Finally I want to put `GradientDrawables` inside, but for debugging purposes I just set a color, to check if it works. 
Here is my Selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:drawable="@color/red"/>
  <item 
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@color/white"/>
   <item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/white"/>
</selector>
```

Unfortunatly this doesn't work. I set the Selector as Button background and only see them in red color. What Am I doing wrong (Build Target 2.1)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

put this at the end

item android:drawable="@color/red"

i mean as the third option, it will work.
android checks the xml conditions from the start, the first tag doesn't have any condition, so it will always pick red, so you have put conditions first and then the default one.

Comment: hmm this doesn't work, because now they are white all the time

Comment: I don't think so. I have two buttons, and they both are white with no change on click

Comment: change the on click color it's white, may be to something other than white.

Comment: I dont't know if this matters: I include the Button Layout inside my mainLayout, because I need them multiple times.

Comment: OHH my... big THX... it works now: Eclipse just want to fool me. I restarted Eclipse and it worked. I just have to put the "empty" item selector as last element...

Comment: if you see your selector, when you click your button background changes to white. so it's obvious you see white when you click on the button.

Comment: ok, if I focus, or click them they change color. What do I have to set if it should stay at this color until the other button is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

here is the code I use, and it works really well.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_clicked"
        android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button" android:state_enabled="true" />
    </selector>
```

here I use two images I made using photoshop as a background

the first is **button_clicked** and the second is **button**

copy it and change use your own resources.

hope I could help :)