# How to grey out a button?

Tags: android, button

I have a button defined as shown below. When I want to disable it I use `my_btn.setEnabled(false)`, but I would also like to grey it out. How can I do that?

Thanks

```
<Button android:id="@+id/buy_btn" style="@style/srp_button" />
```

**style/srp_button**

```
<style name="srp_button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_default</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
</style>
```

**drawable/btn_default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/pink" />
    <corners android:radius="6dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: use a selector http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335345/button-background-selector

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You have to provide 3 or 4 states in your `btn_defaut.xml` as a selector.

1. Pressed state
2. Default state
3. Focus state
4. Enabled state (Disable state with false indication; see comments)

You will provide effect and background for the states accordingly.

Here is a detailed discussion: [Standard Android Button with a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1726352/593709)

Comment: So in order to grey it out, I must change the color of the background AND the color of the text in the disable state? There is no way to just add a transparent foreground?

Comment: Yea! what you will provide for `android:state_disable="true"` it will show the state when the Button is disabled, the easy and recommended way.

Comment: and where can I specify the text color for the disabled state? It seems that only a background can be specified... I asked a new question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743584/how-to-set-the-text-style-of-a-button-in-selectors

Comment: There is no `android:state_disable="true"`, is there? Are you referring to `android:state_enabled="false"`?

Comment: @MarcoW.: yes you are absolutely correct. Apologies for the wrong attribute.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be corrected then? Is this suggestion ok? http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5468508

Answer (score 198):

You could Also make it appear as disabled by setting the alpha (making it semi-transparent). This is especially useful if your button background is an image, and you don't want to create states for it.

```
button.setAlpha(.5f);
button.setClickable(false);
```

**update:** I wrote the above solution pre Kotlin and when I was a rookie. It's more of a "quick'n'dirty" solution, but I don't recommend it in a professional environment.

Today, if I wanted a generic solution that works on any button/view without having to create a state list, I would create a Kotlin extension.

```
fun View.disable() {
    getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)
    setClickable(false)
}
```

In Java you can do something is similar with a static util function and you would just have to pass in the view as variable. It's not as clean but it works.

Comment: I had read that calls to setAlpha are expensive on CPU. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: @AliKazi it depends on the type of your `View`. From [this G+ post](https://plus.google.com/+CyrilMottier/posts/DuAZMhFPDjv): "If your View does not contain overlapping drawing commands, `setAlpha()` is optimized away and we simply modify the Paint objects to apply the proper alpha. This happens when `View.hasOverlappingRendering()` returns true. `ImageView`s and `TextView`s with no background drawable are common candidates for this optimization. If you are in this situation, use `setAlpha()` as much as you want.".

Comment: @Sufian Thanks. But to be on a safer side, I relied on a simple StateListDrawable for each button. How I did that, I've posted as a new answer. I've included links to where I learned that alpha is bad for performance.

Comment: Visually user-unfriendly

Comment: that actually visually disable the view. thanks @Siavash

Comment: `setColorFilter`  is depricated.

Comment: Can this be done in the layout instead of programmatically?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky yes look at the answer below (using a selector xml). But if you're just getting into android I highly recommend learning android Compose instead of layouts. Layouts will be obsolete in a couple of years.

Answer (score 61):

The most easy solution is to set color filter to the background image of a button as I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3485854/1918752)

You can do as follow:

```
if ('need to set button disable')
    button.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
else
    button.getBackground().setColorFilter(null);
```

Hope I helped someone...

Comment: This approach has potential, but the resulting color  isn't always what you think it'll be. For example, an Orange button with the Gray color multiplied results in a dark red color - not a faded orange.

Comment: maybe `Mode.SRC_IN` should be used instead of the Multiply. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17112876/550471

Comment: This works, but two colors when mixed turns into another color

Comment: Awesome! so clean.

Answer (score 37):

All given answers work fine, but I remember learning that using setAlpha can be a [bad idea](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQZFaec9NpA&feature=youtu.be&t=29m51s) performance wise (more info [here](http://www.curious-creature.com/2015/03/25/android-performance-case-study-follow-up/)). So creating a [StateListDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) is a better idea to manage disabled state of buttons. Here's how:

Create a XML btn_blue.xml in res/drawable folder:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Disable background -->
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
          android:color="@color/md_blue_200"/>
    
    <!-- Enabled background -->
    <item android:color="@color/md_blue_500"/>
</selector>
```

Create a button style in res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="BlueButton" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">
      <item name="colorButtonNormal">@drawable/btn_blue</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">@color/md_white_1000</item>
</style>
```

Then apply this style to your button:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/my_disabled_button"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:theme="@style/BlueButton"/>
```

Now when you call `btnBlue.setEnabled(true)` OR `btnBlue.setEnabled(false)` the state colors will automatically switch.

Answer (score 17):

You should create a XML file for the disabled button (**drawable/btn_disable.xml**)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/grey" />
    <corners android:radius="6dp" />
</shape>
```

And create a selector for the button  (**drawable/btn_selector.xml**)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_disable" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default" android:state_pressed="false" />

</selector>
```

Add the selector to your button

```
<style name="srp_button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_selector</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 13):

Set Clickable as false and change the backgroung color as:

```
callButton.setClickable(false);
callButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"));
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried the above solutions but none of them seemed to work for me. I went with the following option:

```
<!-- button_color_selector.xml -->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccentLight" android:state_enabled="false"/>
</selector>
```

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/button_color_selector"
                .../>
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this code for that:

```
ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
matrix.setSaturation(0);
ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
profilePicture.setColorFilter(filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buy_btn);
button.setEnabled(false);
```