# Make checkbox look disabled in Android

Tags: android, checkbox

I want to make a checkbox that offers three different states: unchecked, "half" checked and checked. To stay consistent with the current system style I'd like to use the grayed-out/disabled style for the "half" checked state, but I cant find any drawable that defines this look. How can I make a checkbox look disabled without really disabling it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe using the disabled style on an active button would be confusing, perhaps you should create your own theme instead.

Comment: The checkbox is only used in some sort of "advanced" preferences. In addition there will be a help text. So i don't think it will confuse anybody. And I really want to avoid a custom theme to keep the style consistent.

Answer (score 8):

I spent a long time trying to do exactly what you requested, and finally realized that a fairly simple solution would work (for me, at least). Instead of using my own drawables and styles, or trying to get at undocumented system resources, I just reduce the opacity for the half-checked state, and restore the opacity for the full-checked state. For example, I do the following:

```
if (half_checked)
    checkBox.setAlpha(0.4f);
else
    checkBox.setAlpha(1.0f);
```

This produces a result like the following:
[image: half-checked state]

Answer (score 0):

Since a checkbox is a type of button , any of the states that apply to a button is applicable to it too.

here is a discussion on the different states for an android button
[How to grey out a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743120/how-to-grey-out-a-button)

Comment: But this only helps with creating your own theme. Isn't it possible to just set the default disabled style offered by the OS?

Answer (score 0):

When I've needed similar things, I've setBackground or setTextColor.  You may also be able to make use of setPressed so your three states are (checked, unchecked, and pressed).