# Keep button pressed with default drawings

Tags: android, button

I have button matrix. After button press action I would like to keep that state, after pressing another button I would like to "unpress" first one and keep pressed new one.

I know that I can achieve this with selector and state_pressed but I would like to avoid define my own drawings.
Is there any way to reuse default Android drawings for (un)pressed button? What are the names of them?

Comment: See this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743120/how-to-grey-out-a-button

Comment: I know the method but I wanted to avoid redefine standard drawings for buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is right that using `setPressed(true)` does not keep the button which is being clicked in the pressed state, because after the click the button returns to `setPressed(false)`.

You can override `onTouch` and implement your own behaviour, like this:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    //this is touch
                    v.setPressed(true);
                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    //this is click. Do everything triggered by a click here
                    deselectAllButtons();
                    v.setPressed(true);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

In `deselectAllButtons()` I set all my buttons' pressed states to `false`.

Note that the key idea here is that onClick should not be invoked. That's why onTouch should return true, meaning that the touch event is consumed:

> onTouch() - This returns a boolean to indicate whether your listener
>   consumes this event. The important thing is that this event can have
>   multiple actions that follow each other. So, if you return false when
>   the down action event is received, you indicate that you have not
>   consumed the event and are also not interested in subsequent actions
>   from this event. Thus, you will not be called for any other actions
>   within the event, such as a finger gesture, or the eventual up action
>   event.

Answer (score 1):

Try use [setPressed(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPressed%28boolean%29) on this view

Comment: setPressed is not working on the button which is being clicked. If I set this to different button then it is setting pressed state correctly, but on the "caller" button it only blinks and not being hold in pressed state

Answer (score 1):

In your SDK you can find all Android standard Styles/Drawables. Here is the File you looking for: `sdk\platforms\android-17\data\res\drawable\btn_default.xml` Content:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable" android:state_enabled="false" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_selected" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" android:state_enabled="true"/>      
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable"/>
</selector>
```

Also it would maybe more practible to use a radiobox and a corresponding ControlGroup with theese Styles so you can get easy access to the states programatically

Comment: I'm getting Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/btn_default_normal').

Comment: You have to use the android namespace for default resources like:  @android:drawable/btn_default_normal