# ImageButton - toggle color when pressed

Tags: android, android-button, android-custom-view

How can i toggle the color of an `ImageButton` when user presses the `ImageButton`?

I want the `ImageButton` to toggle between red (power off) and green (power) when pressed.

Code:

```
    ImageButton star, power;
Intent i;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    star = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibStar);
    star.setOnClickListener(this);

    power = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibPower);
    power.setOnTouchListener(this);


}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
        power.setImageResource(R.drawable.power);

    }
     else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {
        power.setImageResource(R.drawable.power_off);

    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you have to clarify what exactly is your problem. It's hard to understand what you want to return.

Comment: After pressing the button changes to green - It works.
By pressing again, I want it to be red (power_off)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need.

```
ImageButton star, power;
Intent i;
boolean isOn=false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    star = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibStar);
    star.setOnClickListener(this);

    power = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibPower);
    power.setOnTouchListener(this);


}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
        isOn=!isOn; // change its state to the oposite one

        if(isOn)
            power.setImageResource(R.drawable.power);
        else
            power.setImageResource(R.drawable.power_off);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: My code works the same way.
I mean here is that when I click the back button again to return to the color red

Comment: @Silesia now it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `OnClickListener` instead of the `OnTouch`. There are a few ways you can handle this situation.

One way is to have a `boolean` that toggles between `true` and `false` signifying if the power is on or off. And then check that value when the `ImageButton` is pressed and change the color of the `ImageButton` accordingly.

```
/* The boolean below is
 * declared in the 
 * class and not in a method. 
 * Whatever default value you need, i assumed false. */
private boolean isPowerOn = false;

power = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibPower);
power.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isPowerOn) {
                /* set color to red */
                isPowerOn = false;
            } else {
                /* set power to green */
                isPowerOn = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

**OR**

You can check the color of the `ImageButton` when it is pressed and then change the color accordingly. This way seems a little funky. Use the `boolean` method.

Comment: I mean the button only
After pressing the button changes to green - It works. By pressing again, I want it to be red (power_off)

Comment: Yeah, i read your comment above and changed your question. Your question is easier to understand now.

Comment: My code works the same way. I mean here is that when I click the back button again to return to the color red

Comment: Updated my answer with your new information, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the button press event show a different color (i.e. during the press event), use a selector, like shown at [Button Background Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335345/button-background-selector).

If you want to have the button color toggle between red and green after an onClick event, then use an onClickListener() (pseudo-code):

```
onClick(ImageButton ib)
{
 if (button is green)
  ib.setImageResource(red)
 else
  ib.setImageResource(green)
}
```