# Highlighting of button,still a mystery?

Tags: android

I am using a button which is having a thick background image.Because of that when i press the button its default higlighting color is not visible.I have tried the image with transparent background but its not working for this particular image.I want to do this programatically.Can anyone help on this?
Thanks.

Comment: do you want to use a simple images for different effects on button> like one image is light and other is dark?

Comment: I just want the button's highlighting color should be visible when i have a thick background.

Comment: I have seen from blogs that they have used button_pressed drawables and some other.Where will it be available,default or customized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default background of a button is a nine patch. If you set your own background you don't get any of the defaults anymore. If you want this you need to provide your own nine patches and a selector similar to this question: [Standard Android Button with a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color)

Comment: I have seen from blogs that they have used button_pressed drawables and some other.Where will it be available,default or customized?