# Adding a button to the titlebar from xml

Tags: android, android-layout, uibutton

I have a problem about the title bar. I want to do 2 buttons in the title bar, but it is seen really bad. First I was thinking I got the button height too big, but when I change the button height nothing is changed. I don't want a custom titlebar and I can't see the text in the button. Can anybody help me?

---

[image: title bar]

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/titleLayout">

    <Button android:id="@+id/done"
            android:layout_width="60dip"
            android:layout_height="38dip"
            android:text="done"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edit"
           >

    </Button>

    <Button android:id="@+id/edit"
            android:layout_width="60dip"
            android:layout_height="38dip"
            android:text="edit"

            >
    </Button>

    </RelativeLayout>



code nippet:

     final boolean customTitle = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); 
       if ( customTitle ) { Window win = getWindow(); 
  win.setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.title);
```

Comment: Did you try to use not fixed size of buttons, but `WRAP_CONTENT` instead of?

Comment: Could you give a code snippet where you set your layout into title?

Comment: Sure.my xml file name is title.I call in my code with this: final boolean customTitle = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
               if ( customTitle ) {
            Window win = getWindow();
            win.setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.title);
        }

Comment: It would be better for everyone if you add this snippet as the edition of your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jsut try to make your `RelativeLayout`'s height WRAP_CONTENT

Comment: It looks like that TitleBar sizes are fixed and they don't change depending on bar's content.

Comment: What will i do have you got any suggestion?

Comment: Define two own <style> xmls, one of them should be derived from `android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar` and another one from `android:WindowTitleBackground` and apply them: first to your <activity> and second to the layout you want to be your custom TitleBar

Comment: I dont want to custom titlebar.Why can not add good looking button?If we can add we can do good looking i think.But i really thanks for reply @teoRetik

Comment: If you would look at Android source code you will see, that there is only one implementation of `Window` class - `PhoneWindow` and only this class use `setFeatureInt` correctly. Other classes only inflate the space of title but not difine it's sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. Before initializing setContentView(), write this line of code

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Then in your layout XML file, include your custom title bar like this.

```
<include layout="@layout/title" android:id="@+id/title"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about just using Text and formatting the background, edges, etc. to make it look like a button. I would try using a TextView, wrap_content and then play with paddings, and background.

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android=" http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android " 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/titleLayout"> 

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/doneBtn" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" 
android:layout_marginRight="10dip" 
android:background="@drawable/bluebutton" 
android:text="Done" 
android:textStyle="bold" 
android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" 
/> 
</RelativeLayout> 

and then in your @drawable/bluebutton.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android=" http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android "> 
<item> 
<shape> 
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#FFBBDDFF" 
        android:centerColor="#FF191990" 
        android:endColor="#FF0000FF" 
        android:angle="270" /> 

  </shape> 
 </item> 
</selector>
```

---

Look at this link for more details I hope it helps... 
[Standard Android Button with a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color)