# LayerDrawable layers padding and rounded corner parts not transparent

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a CustomButton dynamically for java code with 10dp padding and 10dp rounded corners. I wrote the following:

```
public class CustomButton extends Button {

    private GradientDrawable gd;
    private ShapeDrawable sd;
    private LayerDrawable ld;
    private StateListDrawable sld;

    public CustomButton(Context context) {

        super(context);

        gd = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TL_BR, new int[]{Color.parseColor("#39D100"), Color.parseColor("#369212")});
        gd.setCornerRadius(10);

        sd = new PaintDrawable();
        sd.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

        ld = new LayerDrawable( new Drawable[]{sd, gd} );

        sld = new StateListDrawable();
        sld.addState(new int[]{0,1}, ld);

        setBackgroundDrawable(sld);

    }

}
```

If I add only the GradientDrawable or only the ShapeDrawable to StateListDrawable it works correctly, but if I put both into the LayerDrawable the padding and corner parts will have a black background and not transparent as expected.

ScreenShot: 
[image]

Comment: it s 2020 and this is still an issue

Comment: To fix it you gotta draw your own gradient using a RoundRectShape with incrementing insets and alpha values

Answer (score 1):

To remove black background, clear the paint color with

```
sd.getPaint().setColor(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achived with a custom selector for your button, rather than writing up a whole class.
Take a look at this question: [Standard Android Button with a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color)

Comment: Thanks! That was my first idea, but I'm not sure if I can change the gradient from java code.

Comment: Sure you can: <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/colorOne"
                android:endColor="@color/colorTwo"
                android:angle="270" />

Comment: I mean dynamically without xml. I would like to create many different colored gradient buttons with same other parameters.