# Custom circle button

Tags: android, android-button

I want to create custom button and I need it to be circle. How can I create a circle button?
I do not think that be possible with draw9patch.

Also I do not know how to make custom button!

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: you have to extend button class and override the onDraw method.

Comment: but problem is here if I extends that , and user touches out of circle , Onlcick will be called , how to solve this .

Comment: why dont you just set a round shape image as background to your button?

Comment: I did simple OnDrawn , it shows on Design view , but when I want to run application , it makes this problem on loading : android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class com.inaros.magicbox._customButtonPlay

Answer (score 378, accepted):

Use xml drawable like this:

Save the following contents as `round_button.xml` in `drawable` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#fa09ad"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#c20586"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**Android Material Effect:** Although [`FloatingActionButton`](https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) is a better option, If you want to do it using xml selector, create a folder `drawable-v21` in `res` and save another `round_button.xml` there with following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#c20586">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#fa09ad"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

And set it as background of `Button` in xml like this:

```
<Button
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="@drawable/round_button"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:text="hello"
android:textColor="#fff" />
```

**Important:**

1. If you want it to show all these states (enabled, disabled, highlighted etc), you will use selector as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1726352/593709).
2. You've to keep both files in order to make the drawable backward-compatible. Otherwise, you'll face weird exceptions in previous android version.

Comment: By drawable folder you mean to open a folder named 'drawable', or to save it in drawable-mdpi, hdpi, etc...?

Comment: @Jjang no, you just need to save it to 'drawable' folder, any xml resource for drawable is typically saved in 'drawable', not in mdpi, hdpi etc.

Comment: K thx, I had no drawable folder until now (only mdpi, hdpi... and -v21) :)

Comment: P.S How to give the button a default ripple color? Like the grey one that is coloring all the buttons in the app by default.

Comment: @AdilSoomro i need your email address pls or mail me [adilm717@gmail.com](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AdilMadiii),adil from pak

Comment: @Adil Soomro: Is it possible to create inner circle of different radius? and also is it possible to drop shadow? Thanks

Comment: @user1090751 yes, you want to look at [layer-list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList).

Answer (score 69):

Markushi wrote a circle button widget with amazing effects. Click [here](https://github.com/markushi/android-circlebutton)!

[image]

Comment: How to use this with a non circular image?

Comment: Just a heads up: the library linked in this answer is now deprecated. The author (Markushi) recommends using a [Floating Action Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) instead.

Comment: @ABoschman Can we put text in the circle button widget? Or just for drawables

Comment: @RuchirBaronia I think you really should consider the Android FAB. How much prose do you want to place inside a small round button? It seems made for icons. Check out: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#

Comment: @ABoschman Hey, but I really like the effect of this button in this library. Is there any way?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Well, it's up to you. The library is still there, you could possibly use it. Remember though that it's deprecated and no longer being developed. This might become a serious issue in the future.

Comment: can i use it without effects?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica: And FAB too is now deprecated, it is not recommended to use AndroidX.

Answer (score 34):

With the official **Material Components library** you can use the [`MaterialButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) applying a [`Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md#icon-button) style.

Something like:

```
   <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
            app:iconSize="24dp"
            app:iconPadding="0dp"
            android:insetLeft="0dp"
            android:insetTop="0dp"
            android:insetRight="0dp"
            android:insetBottom="0dp"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Rounded"
            />
```

Currently the `app:iconPadding="0dp"`,`android:insetLeft`,`android:insetTop`,`android:insetRight`,`android:insetBottom` attributes are needed to center the icon on the button avoiding extra padding space.

Use the [**`app:shapeAppearanceOverlay`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md) attribute to get rounded corners. In this case you will have a circle.

```
  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
  </style>
```

The final result:

[image]

---

With **jetpack compose** you can use:

```
    Button(
        onClick = { /* Do something! */ },
        modifier = Modifier.width(48.dp).height(48.dp),
        shape = CircleShape
    ) {
        Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, "")
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Gabriele Mariotti. Worth highlighting the need for `app:iconPadding="0dp"` to ensure the icon is centered. I burnt a bunch of time trying center until I found this. It seems an oversight that app:iconGravity is missing a "center" value.

Comment: Thanks @Gabriele Mariotti. Work fine for me!

Comment: To remove the elevation from the button, one can use the following style: Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton.Icon

Answer (score 23):

[AngryTool for custom android button](http://angrytools.com/android/button/)

You can make any kind of custom android button with this tool site...
i make circle and square button with round corner with this toolsite..
Visit it may be i will help you

Answer (score 8):

For a FAB looking button this style on a `MaterialButton`:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton"
    app:cornerRadius="28dp"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:text="1" />
```

Result:

[image]

If you change the size be careful to use half of the button size as `app:cornerRadius`.

Comment: This solution is awesome

Answer (score 7):

You can use MaterialButton from AndroidX material library

```xml
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
     android:layout_width="75dp"
     android:layout_height="75dp"
     android:layout_margin="10dp"
     android:insetLeft="0dp"
     android:insetTop="0dp"
     android:insetRight="0dp"
     android:insetBottom="0dp"
     app:cornerRadius="50dp"
     app:icon="@drawable/ic_camera"
     app:iconGravity="textStart"
     app:iconPadding="0dp"
     app:iconSize="35dp" />
```

and it will be like this

[image: Button preview]

Answer (score 2):

if you want use VectorDrawable and ConstraintLayout

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/ok_button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_button">
                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/icon_of_button"
                        android:layout_width="32dp"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_thumbs_up"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_of_button"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/icon_of_button"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:text="ok"
                        />
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
```

circle background: circle_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="1000dp" />
<solid android:color="#41ba7a" />
<stroke
    android:width="2dip"
    android:color="#03ae3c" />
<padding
    android:bottom="4dp"
    android:left="4dp"
    android:right="4dp"
    android:top="4dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately using an XML drawable and overriding the background means you have to explicitly set the colour instead of being able to use the app style colours.

Rather than hardcode the button colours for every behaviour I opted to hardcode the corner radius, which feels marginally less hacky and retains all the default button behaviour (changing colour when it's pressed and other visual effects) and uses the app style colours by default:

1. Set `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` to the same value
2. Set `app:cornerRadius` to half of the height/width

   (It actually appears that anything greater than or equal to half of the height/width works, so to avoid having to change the radius every time you update the height/width, you could instead set it to a very high value such as `1000dp`, the risk being it could break if this behaviour ever changes.)
3. Set `android:insetBottom` and `android:insetTop` to `0dp` to get a perfect circle

For example:

```xml
<Button
    android:insetBottom="0dp"
    android:insetTop="0dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    app:cornerRadius="75dp"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can perform simply, make a drawable resource file in drawable.xml. Say round_button.xml and then paste the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
       <shape
           android:shape="oval">

           <solid
               android:color="@color/button_start_gradient_color"/>
       </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/microphone"/>
</layer-list>
```

Note:- use your own color and drawable resource as i have used @drawable/microphone

Following is the result
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyhdJ.png

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do with ImageButton, use the following. It will create round ImageButton with material ripples.

```
<ImageButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_6"
android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:padding="10dp"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new vector asset in the drawable folder.

You can import your PNG image as well, and convert the file to SVG online at https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg. The higher the resolution, the better the conversion will be.

Next, create a new vector asset from that SVG file.

This is a sample vector circle image you can use. Copy the code to an xml file in the drawables folder.

ic_check.xml:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="256"
    android:viewportWidth="256">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#2962FF"
        android:pathData="M111,1.7c-7.2,1.1 -22.2,4.8 -27.9,7 -33.2,12.5 -61.3,40.3 -74.1,73.3 -8.7,22.6 -10.5,55.3 -4.4,78 10.9,40 39.7,72.4 77.4,87 22.6,8.7 55.3,10.5 78,4.4 45.3,-12.3 79.1,-46.1 91.4,-91.4 2.9,-10.7 3.9,-21.9 3.3,-37.4 -0.7,-21.2 -4.6,-35.9 -14,-54.1 -18.2,-35 -54,-60.5 -93.4,-66.4 -6.7,-1 -30.7,-1.3 -36.3,-0.4zM145,23.1c21.8,3.3 46.5,16.5 61.1,32.8 20.4,22.6 30.1,51.2 27.7,81.1 -3.5,44.4 -35.9,82.7 -79.6,94 -21.6,5.6 -46.6,3.7 -67.8,-5.1 -10.4,-4.3 -24.7,-14.1 -33.4,-22.9 -41.6,-41.5 -41.6,-108.4 0,-150 24.3,-24.3 57.6,-35.1 92,-29.9z"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#2962FF"
        android:pathData="M148.4,113c-24.6,26 -43.3,44.9 -44,44.6 -0.7,-0.3 -8.5,-6.1 -17.3,-13 -8.9,-6.9 -16.5,-12.6 -17,-12.6 -1.4,-0 -25.6,19 -25.8,20.3 -0.3,1.4 62.7,50.2 64.8,50.2 1.7,-0 108.4,-112.3 108.4,-114.1 0,-1.3 -23.8,-20.4 -25.4,-20.4 -0.6,-0 -20.2,20.3 -43.7,45z"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" />
</vector>
```

Use this image in your button:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_level1"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_check"
/>
```

Your button will be a circle button.

[image]