# Circular Buttons in LinearLayout:Vertical

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have created my own drawable object, which I am setting to be the background of an image button. (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884202/custom-circle-button))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#A7BF1D"/> </shape>
```

I want these to be spaced equally vertically down the side of the screen, so I want to use android:layout_weight to achieve this. (Described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean))

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/left_bar"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_circle"            
            android:text="Call"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
       <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="1"></Space>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSpeak"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_circle"
            android:text="Speak"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
       <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="1"></Space>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRecordedMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_circle"
            android:text="Recorded Message"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="1"></Space>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSelectAll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_circle"
            android:text="Select All Units"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
       <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="1"></Space>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDeselectUnits"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_circle"
            android:text="Deselect Units"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="1"></Space>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAnswer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_circle"
            android:text="Answer"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

What ever I do I cannot seem to have them spaced out equally on any screen size let alone scaled for each of them. I think my issue is that I have to specify height & width to form the circle, but as soon as I do it messes with the layout_weight as its been (for want of a better term) 'hardcoded'.

I assume it is possible to have a vertical layout of 6 circular buttons, spaced equally down the screen but I cannot work out how? I have also tried without the `<Space>`, and added padding to the `<Button>` instead.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you want to have a circle for those buttons no matter the screen dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

Well. For one, all your layout_widths in the LinearLayouts children are set to match_parent. After the first child renders, then there won't be room for anything else because it will take up all the space.

Secondly, I would highly suggest against using all the  tags. Instead I would just set padding (or margins) for your buttons.

Comment: There doesn't need to be room either side of the 'View.Button' objects, I would like them to fill the width of the LinearLayout that contains them, and for the height to be equal that width so that the @drawable/btn_circle is circular, rather than the oval I get at the moment. Only way to make them a circle is by setting height and width, but then they bunch in the top of the view and are not spaced evenly down the length of it.

Comment: The orientation is vertical so the width is irrelevant

Comment: @codeMagic. Thanks. I missed that and that changes everything.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the `View`s inside the `LinearLayout` to be spaced with `weight`. If so, then `android:layout_weight` should be on each `View` and not the `LinearLayout`. The `LinearLayout` would have the `android:weightSum` and each `View` would have the `weight` of say 1. But you don't even need `weightSum` if you want them all spaced evenly.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/left_bar"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="8">  // Try removing this and add weights to your views
```

I don't know if this will fix your problem but I would start with that

Comment: android:layout_weight="8"

That line is there to define the width of the LinearLayout I have a left_bar, middle ImageMap, and right_bar. Basically the final view is a Map object in the middle, with controls on either side. Its for a management app, and the controls are not for android components (zooming scrolling etc..) but for the devices the app controls.

Comment: So this `LinearLayout` is inside another? If so then its height or width should be 0dp depending on the orientation of the parent `LinearLayout

Comment: It is indeed, it is in another LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal". This has 3 child views, the left/right bar and a map.

Comment: Then its `width` should be 0dp. Also, do the widths of all the buttons have a height of 0dp?

Comment: Currently all 3 children in the horizontal layout are set to fill_parent on height and width. The weight is making them the correct width.

Comment: The height in the `LinearLayout` you show here is fine but the width should be 0dp if using weight. I don't understand how giving them a 0 width makes them the right size but I must be missing something

Comment: Yes all buttons are the same, bar the android:text property. I have changed so many things since I added the components on, seeing posts on 'S.O' trying to resolve what I thought would be an easy layout to mock up.

Comment: I have added an Image to try and better show what I have. Currently the left seemingly empty bar is where the buttons have been defined.

Comment: What happens if you do give them a width of say `wrap_content`? One of us is misunderstanding. What I was saying is your `LinearLayout` you show should have a width of 0dp since it is weighted inside of a layout with horizontal orientation

Comment: I set each View in the horizontal layout to have a width of 0dp, and nothing is visible on screen at all now.

Comment: Correct, everything in the horizontal layout now has a width 0.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had to have 4 circular buttons in a horizontal LinearLayout equally spaced.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            style="@style/BotonCircular"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/boton_circulo_negro" />
        <View 
            android:layout_weight="0.033"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            style="@style/BotonCircular"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/boton_circulo_negro" />
        <View 
            android:layout_weight="0.033"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            style="@style/BotonCircular"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/boton_circulo_negro" />
        <View 
            android:layout_weight="0.033"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            style="@style/BotonCircular"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/boton_circulo_negro" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

And to make them all of the same height I placed this code inside onCreate on my Activity

```
final Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
final Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
final Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
final Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
ViewTreeObserver vto = btn1.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        btn1.setHeight(btn1.getWidth()); 
        btn2.setHeight(btn1.getWidth());    
        btn3.setHeight(btn1.getWidth());
        btn4.setHeight(btn1.getWidth());
    }
});
```

Hope this helps someone with the same problem.