# Custom Circle Button that changes the color programatically

Tags: android, android-view, android-button

I want to make a Custom Circle Button as the explained at
[Custom circle button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884202/custom-circle-button) but I also want to change the color of this circle button after making an action. This botton will open a colorpicker, and then what I want is to put the color selected into the button.

How is the best option to this, creating an xml drawable and then refering the color to a variable or something like that, or creating a subclass of button that overrides the onDraw and then draw a circle and can be changed the color of the circle easilly?

Comment: you can use ImageButton

Comment: but I can change the color dinamically of all the palette

Comment: the best option is to create statefull Drawable eg StateListDrawable

Comment: @pskink I will search it, but right now I created a subclass that solves my problem, but I will look for the best option to get the best performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a Circle Button that can change his color programatically I created a subclass of View and then I override the onDraw method to inclide the method drawCircle(). To change the color in another class I created the method changeColor(int) that changes the color of the paint and then draw another circle and invalidate() the view to make the onDraw again.

Here the code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class ColorCircleButton extends View{

private Paint mPaint;
private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
private Bitmap  mBitmap;
private Canvas  mCanvas;
private int width, height;

public ColorCircleButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}
public ColorCircleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}
public ColorCircleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}
private void init() {
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
}
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    width = w;
    height = h;
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    mCanvas.drawCircle(w/2, h/2, h/3, mPaint);
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
}
public void changeColor(int color){
    mPaint.setColor(color);
    mCanvas.drawCircle(width/2, height/2, height/3, mPaint);
    invalidate();
}
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with the changeColor method on this, where mCanvas is showing up null and causing an NPE. This seems to be happening because OnSizeChanged is getting called after changeColor. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can try instantiating the variables in the init method using `getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()`, but I think that maybe that won't work, beacuse probably will return 0, and our circle won't be viewed, beacuse his dimensions will be equal to 0.

Also, I recommend you that if you are not going to change the color of the circle, you can just override in the init the `mPaint.setColor(int)` with the color that you want to have.