# Rounded image button android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have an image button like in the picture.I want the red spaces around it(It will be transparent, just given red to identify the spaces) will not be clickable. Is it possible ? I tried differnt code like via xml or some rounded imageview code but nothing help me..

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884202/custom-circle-button have you tried this one ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

1. get the click coordinates, measure the distance from the center, ignore clicks whose distance from the center is greater than the radius
2. approximate the circle by several clickable square areas, or, probably, place over the original square button several clickable views whose click is ignored, thus covering the areas that should not be clickable.

Comment: why to measure anything, when you can just define shape of your button inside your drawable patter xml file? it is just one line of code in xml:
`<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="oval">`
from now on your button wont react if you press on any corner

Answer (score 7):

No need to calculate anything, the only thing you need to do is to define shape of your imageButton inside button template xml (the drawable on).

so inside your UI layout xml file, ImageButton may be described like this

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="300dp" 
            android:layout_height="300dp" 
            android:src="@drawable/yourIcon" 
            android:background="@drawable/button" <!-- PATTERN!! -->
            android:contentDescription="obrazek"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

and inside your pattern file just declare `shape="oval"` i.e. like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="oval">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#50d050"
        android:endColor="#008000" 
        android:angle="270"/>

    <stroke 
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="#000000"/>

</shape>
```

It cannot be any more simple. :D

Comment: @arun weird, it works for me... :( corners of round button with defined `adnroid:shape="oval"` are not triggering onClick method, sorry i couldn't help :(

Comment: @arun i've tried this with bigger buttons, and it appears, that when i touched screen near border of button, but outside of it, it still trigger onClick event....
It appears that the only reasonable solution is with calculation proposed by user 18446744073709551615