# Android: Create circle looks button with background image

Tags: android, button, layout

Hello guys i know this is not a new question. I am getting help from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884202/custom-circle-button). In which i have success to make circle button with plane background but i want to make a button with background image like this:

[image: Sample image]

**Here is related code for the layout:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/lighter_gray"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
        android:background="@drawable/button_circular"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".18"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/lighter_gray"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**@drawable/button_circular**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/app_main_color"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/app_main_color" />
</shape>
```

I also want to know is this a right way to get button like this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Imageview Instead of Button

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
    android:background="@drawable/button_circular"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".18"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: That is mentioned in the question it's a xml and code is given with question.