# Android circular button clickable area

Tags: android, user-interface, android-studio

I've made this circular button in Android Studio:

[image]

I used a custom backgroud. The problem is that the highlighted yellow area in the image, is clickable. I want to reduce the clickable area to just the red circle.

Is there any way to do such thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **cannot** remove that transparent area of your image. Because it's a part of your image.

Any kind of image always have **rectangular shape**. If the corners of the image are transparent, doesn't mean those *pixels at the corner are separated from the image!* Those pixels are **always occupied by your image** and you cannot remove that area.

No library yet created that can apart transparent area of an image from image itself.

Comment: Hi @Apurva I don't want that the transparent area of my image be clickable.

Comment: @RenatoReyes it is not possible, because you cannot apart those pixels from your image. I have never ever seen anybody anywhere who could make this possible. Create your own library and put over internet, you'll be hero.

Answer (score 2):

There was a previous post regarding to [clickable area of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670774/clickable-area-of-image) but.. it might not solve this case here.

Instead, you should use [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) to get the x and y of the touch event, then calculate and compare the distance between the center and the even with the radius in order to determine if this is a value click.

Answer (score 0):

Better later than never...

**Yes**, you can manually reduce the clickable area to just the red circle if you intercept and filter the touch events, by implementing a [View.OnTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener) or overriding [onTouchEvent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)). The latter requires you to subclass your button, which is easy enough but maybe not quite as desirable, so here is an example of using `View.OnTouchListener` to do the job:

**OvalTouchAreaFilter.java:**

```
public class OvalTouchAreaFilter implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private boolean mIgnoreCurrentGesture;

    public TouchAreaFilter() {
        mIgnoreCurrentGesture = false;
    }

    public boolean isInTouchArea(View view, float x, float y) {
        int w = view.getWidth();
        int h = view.getHeight();
        if(w <= 0 || h <= 0)
            return false;
        float xhat = 2*x / w - 1;
        float yhat = 2*y / h - 1;
        return (xhat * xhat + yhat * yhat <= 1);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getActionMasked();
        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            mIgnoreCurrentGesture = !this.isInTouchArea(view, event.getX(), event.getY());
            return mIgnoreCurrentGesture;
        }
        boolean ignoreCurrentGesture = mIgnoreCurrentGesture;
        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
            mIgnoreCurrentGesture = false;
        return ignoreCurrentGesture;
    }
}
```

**Inside activity onCreate():**

```
View button = findViewById(R.id.my_button);
button.setOnTouchListener(new OvalTouchAreaFilter());
```

Note that:

- `isInTouchArea()` can be arbitrarily implemented to set the clickable area to whatever shape you want, even potentially dependent on complex conditions like the background image of the button, etc.
- `setOnTouchListener()` is not specific to the `Button` class. This solution can be used with any type of view whatsoever.
- It is not a good solution to just blindly filter all touch messages based on their X and Y position (e.g. as suggested in answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090386/create-imageview-that-is-round-so-click-will-work-on-round-area-only-android)), as you thereby break the [MotionEvent consistency guarantee](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#consistency-guarantees). This solution instead filters out *complete gestures* (sequences of `MotionEvent`'s starting with `ACTION_DOWN` and ending with `ACTION_UP`/`ACTION_CANCEL`, with possibly many other actions inbetween like `ACTION_MOVE`) based on their starting coordinates. This means that the approach doesn't break in multi-touch situations.

Answer (score -2):

Create xml drawable like this:

save it as round_button.xml in drawable folder

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#9F2200"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#fff" />
</shape>
```

and set it as background of Button in xml like this:`

```
<Button
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="@drawable/round_button"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:text="hello"
android:textColor="#fff" />
```

Comment: I've already done that, dude. I just wanna know how to reduce the clickable area.