# Perfectly Round Buttons in android

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I need perfect circle button in my app. Which scales automatically accordingly to the screen size(height of the layout it is in.)

My xml file : `circle1try.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <corners
        android:radius="1000dp"
    />
    <solid
        android:color="#ff00b3ff"
    />
</shape>
```

the place where I use it in my activity layout :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button1Key"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle1try"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:text="tap here"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The entire `LinearLayout` lies in another vertical `LinearLayout` and I use `layout_weight` to make sure the space occupied by the layouts have similar proportions on all screens.

This code snippet from the java file related to the button

```
roundButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1Key);
int btnSize=roundButton.getLayoutParams().height;
roundButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(btnSize, btnSize));
```

and in my app depending on the user actions, I also need to change the color for which I use the following snippet in the same class.

```
bgShape = (GradientDrawable)roundButton.getBackground();
bgShape.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

However the button I get using this process is not a complete circle.
It is close to a circle but wide along the x axis.
So how do I get a perfectly round button whose color can be easily changed ?

Comment: isn't `1000dp` for the radius too much?

Comment: Using `<corners />` with `shape:"oval"`?

Comment: but it doesn't produce any different result from `100dp` radius or `10dp` radius . Not sure what to  do about it.

Comment: I tried with `shape:"rectangle" and `shape:"oval", with the later `removing `<corners />` doesn't make any difference, I still get the same result.

Comment: @AakashMaroti That was the point. Using `<corners />` with `shape:oval` does nothing. Add a picture of what your activity looks like now.

Comment: @Vikram , I do not have enough reputation to post a pic, but here is the link, I have inscribed a perfect circle inside for reference  [image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0YRqSOqDC6bbmRVSWQwOVJoeUU&authuser=0)

Comment: @AakashMaroti Seems like your width is at the maximum, but still less than the height. As an experiment, use `int btnSize=roundButton.getLayoutParams().width;`. Does that produce a _perfect circle_?

Comment: @Vikram It just gets worse using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ! so what basically does not  work with the code is that it scales up the shape even before the layout is drawn. solution ? wait for the layout to be drawn.
Initially `getHeight()` would return `0`.
I used a ViewTreeObserver.
Now it returns the actual value.
Code snippet I incorporated that solved my problem.

```
     ViewTreeObserver vto = player.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            roundButton.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            roundButton.setWidth(player.getHeight());                
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params=roundButton.getLayoutParams();
            params.width=player.getHeight();
            roundButton.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library :
[AndroidCircleButton](https://github.com/markushi/android-circlebutton)

or 
look at [another answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884202/custom-circle-button)

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible without  using any external liabrary, and also avoid measurements in `dp` as I want to get largest possible shape which fits the proportions of the `LinearLayout`.